# sudo echo "something" >> /etc/privilegedFile doesn't work

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, permissions, sudo

This is a pretty simple question, at least it seems like it should be, about sudo permissions in Linux.

There are a lot of times when I just want to append something to `/etc/hosts` or a similar file but end up not being able to because both `>` and `>>` are not allowed, even with root.

Is there someway to make this work without having to `su` or `sudo su` into root?

Answer (score 1111, accepted):

Use `tee --append` or `tee -a`.

```
echo 'deb blah ... blah' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Make sure to avoid quotes inside quotes.

To avoid printing data back to the console, redirect the output to /dev/null.

```
echo 'deb blah ... blah' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list > /dev/null
```

Remember about the (`-a`/`--append`) flag! 
Just `tee` works like `>` and will overwrite your file. `tee -a` works like `>>` and will write at the end of the file.

Comment: I absolutely prefer this one. It's just the simplest (and it tought me about tee, which comes in handy in other scenarios as well).

Comment: I agree. Seems neater than start a new sh too, especially with potentially to do things with environment etc.

Comment: One important thing to note: NEVER forget the -a! Just imagine what a `echo 'tmpfs /tmp tmpfs defaults 0 0' | sudo tee /etc/fstab` would do

Comment: Under OS X, this should be `tee -a` instead of `tee --append`.

Comment: For those who don't understand what @mic_e said: **without the `-a`** (`--append`) flag **the command would overwrite the whole file** with the given string instead of appending it to the end.

Comment: For the record, you want `-a` on Ubuntu Server 16.04, `--append` is ignored as @totymedli illustrates.

Answer (score 360):

The problem is that the shell does output redirection, not sudo or echo, so this is being done as your regular user.

Try the following code snippet:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'something' >> /etc/privilegedfile"
```

Comment: What are "sudo permission boundaries"? It's just the shell which parses the redirection operator with higher precedence than a command for obvious reasons

Comment: Depending on your `sh`, echo can interpret escape sequences like `\t` inside single quotes. You could use `printf %s 'something'` instead.

Comment: Using **tee** is more popular and more compatible to newer distros.

Comment: This is the only one which works as-is as an SSH command which can be executed on a remote node.

Comment: I agree with other posts here. This uses a shell and only shell so another program like tee is not required here. Yes I know tee is installed already, but maybe not depending on what micro distro you're using like bare bones alpine. I like that you have a shell option too: `sudo /bin/bash -c "echo 'fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 524288' > /etc/sysctl.d/60-golang-inotify.conf"` for example.

Comment: great, this way you can also repeat the last command as sudo: `sudo sh -c "!!"`

Answer (score 37):

The issue is that it's your shell that handles redirection; it's trying to open the file with *your* permissions not those of the process you're running under sudo.

Use something like this, perhaps:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'something' >> /etc/privilegedFile"
```

Comment: @GordonSun this is because `sudo` (for security reasons) doesn't propagate the environment to the subprocess.  You may use `sudo -E` to bypass this restriction.

Comment: @GordonSun yes it will, I don't understand why you keep repeating this statement! If you do `sudo sh -c "echo 'something' >> $FILENAME"`, with double quotes, this *will* work - the variable substitution is done by the outer shell, not the sudoed shell.

Comment: does not work with multiline echo

Answer (score 23):

```
sudo sh -c "echo 127.0.0.1 localhost >> /etc/hosts"
```

Answer (score 16):

Doing

```
sudo sh -c "echo >> somefile"
```

should work. The problem is that > and >> are handled by your shell, not by the "sudoed" command, so the permissions are your ones, not the ones of the user you are "sudoing" into.

Answer (score 11):

I would note, for the curious, that you can also quote a heredoc (for large blocks):

```
sudo bash -c "cat <<EOIPFW >> /etc/ipfw.conf
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>

<plist version=\"1.0\">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.company.ipfw</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/sbin/ipfw</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/sbin/ipfw</string>
      <string>-q</string>
      <string>/etc/ipfw.conf</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true></true>
  </dict>
</plist>
EOIPFW"
```

Comment: This works great, except the embedded quotes might need to be escaped with a \

Comment: Quite right @NJones! I shall edit my answer. (Note, however, that not doing this strips the internal `"` but does not cause the command to fail.)

Answer (score 10):

In bash you can use `tee` in combination with `> /dev/null` to keep stdout clean.

```
 echo "# comment" |  sudo tee -a /etc/hosts > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 10):

Some user not know solution when using multiples lines.

```
sudo tee -a  /path/file/to/create_with_text > /dev/null <<EOT 
line 1
line 2
line 3
EOT
```

Answer (score 5):

Using [Yoo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/550808/983883), put this in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
sudoe() {
    [[ "$#" -ne 2 ]] && echo "Usage: sudoe <text> <file>" && return 1
    echo "$1" | sudo tee --append "$2" > /dev/null
}
```

Now you can run `sudoe 'deb blah # blah' /etc/apt/sources.list`

---

**Edit:**

A more complete version which allows you to pipe input in or redirect from a file and includes a `-a` switch to turn off appending (which is on by default):

```
sudoe() {
  if ([[ "$1" == "-a" ]] || [[ "$1" == "--no-append" ]]); then
    shift &>/dev/null || local failed=1
  else
    local append="--append"
  fi

  while [[ $failed -ne 1 ]]; do
    if [[ -t 0 ]]; then
      text="$1"; shift &>/dev/null || break
    else
      text="$(cat <&0)"
    fi

    [[ -z "$1" ]] && break
    echo "$text" | sudo tee $append "$1" >/dev/null; return $?
  done

  echo "Usage: $0 [-a|--no-append] [text] <file>"; return 1
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `sponge` from the `moreutils` package and not need to redirect the output (i.e., no `tee` noise to hide):

```
echo 'Add this line' | sudo sponge -a privfile
```

Comment: ```-a``` appends to file.

Comment: @Akhil, if you have a question, please leave a meaningful comment. If you have a statement or concern, please leave a meaningful comment. If you see an error or omission, please leave a meaningful comment. Do you see a pattern developing in my statements?

Answer (score 2):

By using **sed -i**  with **$ a** , you can append text, containing both variables and special characters, after the last line.

For example, adding $NEW_HOST with $NEW_IP to /etc/hosts:

```
sudo sed -i "\$ a $NEW_IP\t\t$NEW_HOST.domain.local\t$NEW_HOST" /etc/hosts
```

sed options explained:

- ***-i*** for in-place
- ***$*** for last line
- ***a*** for append

Comment: I think you've been downvoted because only GNU sed lets you put text immediately after the command.  On OSX I had to actually use line breaks AND the -e option:
`sudo sed -ie '$a\ ` <newline> `> export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="adapter-gcp-compute-test-WWWXXXYYYZZZ.json"` <newline>
`> ' /Users/gcpclient/.bashrc`

Answer (score 0):

echo 'Hello World' | (sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list)

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:
original command

```
echo "export CATALINA_HOME="/opt/tomcat9"" >> /etc/environment
```

Working command

```
echo "export CATALINA_HOME="/opt/tomcat9"" |sudo tee /etc/environment
```

Comment: Should be `tee -a`.  Just `tee` will overwrite the file!

Answer (score -1):

How about:
echo text | sudo dd status=none of=privilegedfile
I want to change /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_rmem.
I did:
  sudo dd status=none of=/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_rmem <<<"4096 131072 1024000"
eliminates the echo with a single line document

Comment: Please take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the [help]. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.

Answer (score -6):

Can you change the ownership of the file then change it back after using `cat >>` to append?

```
sudo chown youruser /etc/hosts  
sudo cat /downloaded/hostsadditions >> /etc/hosts  
sudo chown root /etc/hosts
```

Something like this work for you?

Comment: Chown is a destructive command to use.  If a config manager used that to update /etc/hosts, suddenly /etc/hosts belongs to config user and not root. which potentially leads to other processes not having access to /etc/hosts.  The whole point of sudo is to avoid having something logged into root and via sudoers more restrictions can be piled on as well.