# Appending a line to a file only if it does not already exist

Tags: linux, sed, terminal

I need to add the following line to the end of a config file:

```
include "/configs/projectname.conf"
```

to a file called `lighttpd.conf`

I am looking into using `sed` to do this, but I can't work out how.

How would I only insert it if the line doesn't already exist?

Comment: If you are trying to edit an ini-file the tool [`crudini`](https://github.com/pixelb/crudini) might be a good option (but not for lighthttpd yet)

Comment: Perhaps see also [sed,awk.grep - add a line to the end of a configuration section if the line doesn't already exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16102213/sed-awk-grep-add-a-line-to-the-end-of-a-configuration-section-if-the-line-does)

Answer (score 485, accepted):

Just keep it simple :)

**grep** + **echo** should suffice:

```
grep -qxF 'include "/configs/projectname.conf"' foo.bar || echo 'include "/configs/projectname.conf"' >> foo.bar
```

- `-q` be quiet
- `-x` match the whole line
- `-F` pattern is a plain string
- https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep

*Edit:
incorporated @cerin and @thijs-wouters suggestions*.

Comment: This one does the reverse of what I need. It only adds the line to the file IF the line already exists. I only want to add it if it doesnt exist. Any ideas?

Comment: sorry forgotten a "-v" optiont to grep, or substitute && with || :)

I'm going to correct, thanks

Comment: I would add the -q switch to grep to suppress output:  `grep -vq ...`

Comment: FYI, using -v and && doesn't look to do the trick, whereas || without -v works.

Comment: Thanks guys, but this command still continues to add a brand new line if that line already exists. It should only write one if it doesnt exist. For testing i have been running:

grep -vq 'include "/configs/projectname.conf"' text.txt || echo 'include "/configs/projectname.conf"' >> text.txt

Comment: OK i've only managed to get it work by doing this:

grep 'include "/configs/projectname.conf"' text.txt || echo 'include "/configs/projectname.conf"' >> text.txt

Comment: This only works for very simple lines. Otherwise, grep interprets most non-alpha characters in your line as patterns, causing it to not detect the line in the file.

Comment: Note, using `-F` seems to fix my issue.

Comment: The way was indicated .. the answer was for a specific question :)

Of course anybody can/has to adjust to his needs ... maybe -F gives a bit more robustness too .. Tnx

Comment: Beautiful solution. This also works for triggering more complicated expressions, of course. Mine uses the `echo` to trigger a `cat` of a multiline heredoc into a config file.

Comment: Doesn't work when sudo is required? Prepending `sudo` to the `grep` and `echo` commands doesn't work..

Comment: Add `-s` to ignore errors when the file does not exist, creating a new file with just that line.

Comment: You need to add an -x option to ensure only the entire line matches, instead of only part of a line.

Comment: Would be better if can add a example to show appending multiple lines to a file if it does not exist .

Comment: The text to be appended appears in the expression twice.
How about prepending the command with `ADDTEXT='include "/configs/projectname.conf"'` and then using `$ADDTEXT`?
The same goes for the file name `foo.bar`.

Comment: How about appending multiple lines only if they don't exist

Comment: `grep` + `echo` is usually more simply done with `awk`

Comment: With the -x option it doesn't work for me, it just adds it over and over 
`grep -qxF '/src/styles/_js_variables.scss' .gitignore || echo "/src/styles/_js_variables.scss" >> .gitignore`
But works without the -x, I think with the -x it interprets it as a regex and defeats the -F flag

Comment: @Tofandel what OS and grep version are you using?

Comment: @JeanSpector agreed, like `s='include "/configs/projectname.conf"'; f=foo.bar; grep -qxF "$s" "$f" || echo "$s" >> "$f"`

Answer (score 111):

This would be a clean, readable and reusable solution using `grep` and `echo` to add a line to a file only if it doesn't already exist:

```
LINE='include "/configs/projectname.conf"'
FILE='lighttpd.conf'
grep -qF -- "$LINE" "$FILE" || echo "$LINE" >> "$FILE"
```

If you need to match the whole line use `grep -xqF`

Add `-s` to ignore errors when the file does not exist, creating a new file with just that line.

Comment: If it's to a file where you need root permissions: `sudo grep -qF "$LINE" "$FILE" ||  echo "$LINE" | sudo tee -a "$FILE"`

Comment: This actually doesn't work when the line starts with a `-`.

Comment: @zsero: good point! I added `--` in the grep command, so it will not interpret a $LINE starting with a dash as options any more.

Answer (score 104):

Try this:

```
grep -q '^option' file && sed -i 's/^option.*/option=value/' file || echo 'option=value' >> file
```

Comment: For an explanation see: [explainshell](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=grep+-q+%27%5Eoption%27+file+%26%26+sed+-i+%27s%2F%5Eoption.*%2Foption%3Dvalue%2F%27+file+%7C%7C+echo+%27option%3Dvalue%27+%3E%3E+file)

Comment: Marc Wäckerlin's answer is more comprehensive and does everything requested in one sed.  Additionally, the use of && and || is ambiguous (can the || apply to grep and the sed, what happens if sed returns false?

Comment: I used this for a task at my work. Worked like a charm. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 48):

Using sed, the simplest syntax:

```
sed \
    -e '/^\(option=\).*/{s//\1value/;:a;n;ba;q}' \
    -e '$aoption=value' filename
```

This would replace the parameter if it exists, else would add it to the bottom of the file.

Use the `-i` option if you want to edit the file in-place.

---

If you want to accept and keep white spaces, and in addition to remove the comment, if the line already exists, but is commented out, write:

```
sed -i \
    -e '/^#\?\(\s*option\s*=\s*\).*/{s//\1value/;:a;n;ba;q}' \
    -e '$aoption=value' filename
```

Please note that neither option nor value must contain a slash `/`, or you will have to escape it to `\/`.

---

To use bash-variables `$option` and `$value`, you could write:

```
sed -i \
    -e '/^#\?\(\s*'${option//\//\\/}'\s*=\s*\).*/{s//\1'${value//\//\\/}'/;:a;n;ba;q}' \
    -e '$a'${option//\//\\/}'='${value//\//\\/} filename
```

The bash expression `${option//\//\\/}` quotes slashes, it replaces all `/` with `\/`.

*Note:* Just trapped into a problem. In bash you may quote `"${option//\//\\/}"`, but in the sh of busybox, this does not work, so you should avoid the quotes, at least in non-bourne-shells.

---

All combined in a bash function:

```
# call option with parameters: $1=name $2=value $3=file
function option() {
    name=${1//\//\\/}
    value=${2//\//\\/}
    sed -i \
        -e '/^#\?\(\s*'"${name}"'\s*=\s*\).*/{s//\1'"${value}"'/;:a;n;ba;q}' \
        -e '$a'"${name}"'='"${value}" $3
}
```

---

**Explanation:**

- `/^\(option=\).*/`: Match lines that start with `option=` and (`.*`) ignore everything after the `=`. The `\(`…`\)` encloses the part we will reuse as `\1`later.
- /^#?(\s*'"${option//////}"'\s*=\s*).*/: Ignore commented out code with `#` at the begin of line. `\?` means «optional». The comment will be removed, because it is outside of the copied part in `\(`…`\)`. `\s*` means «any number of white spaces» (space, tabulator). White spaces are copied, since they are within `\(`…`\)`, so you do not lose formatting.
- `/^\(option=\).*/{…}`: If matches a line `/…/`, then execute the next command. Command to execute is not a single command, but a block `{…}`.
- `s//…/`: Search and replace. Since the search term is empty `//`, it applies to the last match, which was `/^\(option=\).*/`.
- `s//\1value/: Replace the last match with everything in` (…)`, referenced by` \1`and the text`value`
- `:a;n;ba;q`: Set label `a`, then read next line `n`, then branch `b` (or goto) back to label `a`, that means: read all lines up to the end of file, so after the first match, just fetch all following lines without further processing. Then `q` quit and therefore ignore everything else.
- `$aoption=value`: At the end of file `$`, append `a` the text `option=value`

More information on `sed` and a command overview is on my blog:

- [https://marc.wäckerlin.ch/computer/stream-editor-sed-overview-and-reference](https://marc.xn--wckerlin-0za.ch/computer/stream-editor-sed-overview-and-reference)

Comment: how this would be for files like "option value"? When I replace = for a space the function fix the option, but the rest of the file is lost :(

Comment: @jlanza, I am very sorry, there was a typo in my code. The command is «ba», not «:ba». I edited the text and fixed it. Please try again.

Comment: You could escape the `/` character by using another character in the substitution command (like `!`): `sed -i -e '/^\(option=\).*/{s!!\1value!;:a;n;ba;q}' -e '$aoption=value' filename`

Comment: Yes,you can use any character for the sed command. In fact I often use the comma: `sed 's,from,to,g'`, but to allow arbitrary name value pairs, e.g. arguments from a function call, you still need to escape them.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that a file `filename` or `$3` must not be empty

Comment: Hi, this helped me, but I have an issue, if I have `#option=value` at the first line of the file and `option=value` as the last line of the file, I ended up with two line with the same information. Is there anyway to handle this?

Comment: Also requires non empty file to exist

Comment: Awesome answer. To make it perfect I would add `local -r` to vars to make it local and inmutable, like `local -r filepath="${3}"`

Comment: When writing a script, I prefer a readable/maintainable style over terse `;`-concatenated commands.   Ref. https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-61

Answer (score 22):

If writing to a protected file, @drAlberT and @rubo77 's answers might not work for you since one can't sudo `>>`.  A [similarly simple solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84882/sudo-echo-something-etc-privilegedfile-doesnt-work-is-there-an-alterna), then, would be to use `tee --append` (or, on MacOS, `tee -a`):

```
LINE='include "/configs/projectname.conf"'
FILE=lighttpd.conf
grep -qF "$LINE" "$FILE"  || echo "$LINE" | sudo tee --append "$FILE"
```

Comment: You can also use sed so you could insert this line where you want. `grep -qF "$LINE" "$FILE"  || sudo sed -i "/line_where_you_want_to_insert_before/i $LINE" "$FILE"`

Answer (score 16):

Here's a `sed` version:

```
sed -e '\|include "/configs/projectname.conf"|h; ${x;s/incl//;{g;t};a\' -e 'include "/configs/projectname.conf"' -e '}' file
```

If your string is in a variable:

```
string='include "/configs/projectname.conf"'
sed -e "\|$string|h; \${x;s|$string||;{g;t};a\\" -e "$string" -e "}" file
```

Comment: For a command that replaces a partial string with the complete/updated config file entry, or appends the line as needed: `sed -i -e '\|session.*pam_mkhomedir.so|h; ${x;s/mkhomedir//;{g;tF};a\' -e 'session\trequired\tpam_mkhomedir.so umask=0022' -e '};:F;s/.*mkhomedir.*/session\trequired\tpam_mkhomedir.so umask=0022/g;' /etc/pam.d/common-session`

Comment: Nice, it helped me a lot +1. could you please, explain your sed expression ?

Comment: I'd love to see an annotated explanation of this solution. I've used `sed` for years but mostly just the `s` command. The `hold` and `pattern` space swaps are beyond me.

Answer (score 12):

If, one day, someone else **have** to deal with this code as "legacy code", then that person will be grateful if you write a less exoteric code, such as

```
grep -q -F 'include "/configs/projectname.conf"' lighttpd.conf
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  echo 'include "/configs/projectname.conf"' >> lighttpd.conf
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment Graham! Yes, it's normal shell syntax.  And yes, any competent admin ought to understand it.  However, it works as such based on a side effect of the expression evaluation algorithm within shell.  So you can call it all you like, except straightforward -- which was my original point.

Comment: See also [Why is testing "$?" to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern)

Answer (score 10):

another sed solution is to always append it on the last line and delete a pre existing one.

```
sed -e '$a\' -e '<your-entry>' -e "/<your-entry-properly-escaped>/d"
```

"properly-escaped" means to put a regex that matches your entry, i.e. to escape all regex controls from your actual entry, i.e. to put a backslash in front of ^$/*?+().

this might fail on the last line of your file or if there's no dangling newline, I'm not sure, but that could be dealt with by some nifty branching...

Comment: Nice one-liner, short and easy to read. Works great for updating etc/hosts: `sed -i.bak -e '$a\' -e "$NEW_IP\t\t$HOST.domain\t$HOST" -e "/.*$HOST/d" /etc/hosts`

Comment: A smaller version: `sed -i -e '/<entry>/d; $a <entry>'`

Comment: @Jezz I think this will fail, if the entry already is at the end of the file, because the `d` command will restart the sed programm and thereby skip the `a`ppend, if the delete happened to be on the last line.

Comment: @Robin479 Damned, `a`ppend have to be executed before `d`elete: `sed -i -e '$a<entry>' -e '/<entry>/d'`. It is nearly the same than your original answer.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a one-liner sed which does the job inline. Note that **it preserves the location of the variable and its indentation** in the file when it exists. This is often important for the context, like when there are comments around or when the variable is in an indented block. Any solution based on "delete-then-append" paradigm fails badly at this.

```
   sed -i '/^[ \t]*option=/{h;s/=.*/=value/};${x;/^$/{s//option=value/;H};x}' test.conf
```

With a generic pair of variable/value you can write it this way:

```
   var=c
   val='12 34' # it handles spaces nicely btw
   sed -i '/^[ \t]*'"$var"'=/{h;s/=.*/='"$val"'/};${x;/^$/{s//c='"$val"'/;H};x}' test.conf
```

---

Finally, if you want also to keep inline comments, you can do it with a catch group. E.g. if `test.conf` contains the following:

```
a=123
# Here is "c":
  c=999 # with its own comment and indent
b=234
d=567
```

Then running this

```
var='c'
val='"yay"'
sed -i '/^[ \t]*'"$var"'=/{h;s/=[^#]*\(.*\)/='"$val"'\1/;s/'"$val"'#/'"$val"' #/};${x;/^$/{s//'"$var"'='"$val"'/;H};x}' test.conf
```

Produces that:

```
a=123
# Here is "c":
  c="yay" # with its own comment and indent
b=234
d=567
```

Comment: Nice solution but an explanation of the code would be appreciated

Answer (score 6):

As an awk-only one-liner:

```
awk -v s=option=value '/^option=/{$0=s;f=1} {a[++n]=$0} END{if(!f)a[++n]=s;for(i=1;i<=n;i++)print a[i]>ARGV[1]}' file
```

ARGV[1] is your input `file`. It is opened and written to in the `for` loop of the`END` block. Opening `file` for output in the `END` block replaces the need for utilities like `sponge` or writing to a temporary file and then `mv`ing the temporary file to `file`.

The two assignments to array `a[]` accumulate all output lines into `a`. `if(!f)a[++n]=s` appends the new `option=value` if the main awk loop couldn't find `option` in `file`.

I have added some spaces (not many) for readability, but you really need just one space in the whole awk program, the space after `print`.
If `file` includes `# comments` they will be preserved.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an `awk` implementation

```
/^option *=/ { 
  print "option=value"; # print this instead of the original line
  done=1;               # set a flag, that the line was found
  next                  # all done for this line
}
{print}                 # all other lines -> print them
END {                   # end of file
  if(done != 1)         # haven't found /option=/ -> add it at the end of output
    print "option=value"
}
```

Run it using

```
awk -f update.awk < /etc/fdm_monitor.conf > /etc/fdm_monitor.conf.tmp && \
   mv /etc/fdm_monitor.conf.tmp /etc/fdm_monitor.conf
```

or

```
awk -f update.awk < /etc/fdm_monitor.conf | sponge /etc/fdm_monitor.conf
```

EDIT:
As a one-liner:

```
awk '/^option *=/ {print "option=value";d=1;next}{print}END{if(d!=1)print "option=value"}' /etc/fdm_monitor.conf | sponge /etc/fdm_monitor.conf
```

Comment: I need a one liner cause i send this as a system call from a c programm.

Answer (score 3):

use awk

```
awk 'FNR==NR && /configs.*projectname\.conf/{f=1;next}f==0;END{ if(!f) { print "your line"}} ' file file
```

Comment: Is it 'file file' or just 'file' ?

Comment: It's `file file` because it makes two passes over the same file. `NR==FNR` is true on the first pass, but not the second. This is a common Awk idiom.

Answer (score 3):

```
 sed -i 's/^option.*/option=value/g' /etc/fdm_monitor.conf
 grep -q "option=value" /etc/fdm_monitor.conf || echo "option=value" >> /etc/fdm_monitor.conf
```

Answer (score 2):

here is an awk one-liner:

```
 awk -v s="option=value" '/^option/{f=1;$0=s}7;END{if(!f)print s}' file
```

this doesn't do in-place change on the file, you can however :

```
awk '...' file > tmpfile && mv tmpfile file
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`, you could say:

```
sed -e '/option=/{s/.*/option=value/;:a;n;:ba;q}' -e 'aoption=value' filename
```

This would replace the parameter if it exists, else would add it to the bottom of the file.

---

Use the `-i` option if you want to edit the file in-place:

```
sed -i -e '/option=/{s/.*/option=value/;:a;n;:ba;q}' -e 'aoption=value' filename
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work at all. It adds "option=value" after every line. Not sure how it got two upvotes. You could do '$aoption=value' but I can't seem to make that conditional on the previous match so it just appends to the end regardless.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -i '1 h
1 !H
$ {
   x
   s/^option.*/option=value/g
   t
   s/$/\
option=value/
   }' /etc/fdm_monitor.conf
```

Load all the file in buffer, at the end, change all occurence and if no change occur, add to the end

Answer (score 2):

The answers using grep are wrong. You need to add an -x option to match the entire line otherwise lines like `#text to add` will still match when looking to add exactly `text to add`.

So the correct solution is something like:

```
grep -qxF 'include "/configs/projectname.conf"' foo.bar || echo 'include "/configs/projectname.conf"' >> foo.bar
```

Answer (score 2):

Almost all of the answers work but not in all scenarios or OS as per my experience. Only thing that worked on older systems and new and different flavours of OS is the following.
I needed to append KUBECONFIG path to bashrc file if it doesnt exist. So, what I did is

I assume that it exists and delete it.
with sed I append the string I want.

```
sed -i '/KUBECONFIG=/d' ~/.bashrc

echo 'export KUBECONFIG=/etc/rancher/rke2/rke2.yaml' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: SIMPLEST EFECTIVE COMMAND EVER THANKS

Answer (score 1):

**Using sed:** It will insert at the end of line. You can also pass in variables as usual of course.

```
grep -qxF "port=9033" $light.conf
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  sed -i "$ a port=9033" $light.conf
else
    echo "port=9033 already added"
fi
```

**Using oneliner sed**

```
grep -qxF "port=9033" $lightconf || sed -i "$ a port=9033" $lightconf
```

**Using echo** may not work under root, but will work like this. But it will not let you automate things if you are looking to do it since it might ask for password.

I had a problem when I was trying to edit from the root for a particular user. Just adding the `$username` before was a fix for me.

```
grep -qxF "port=9033" light.conf
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  sudo -u $user_name echo "port=9033" >> light.conf
else
    echo "already there"    
fi
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please read the question carefully before posting an answer - the OP asked how to insert using sed

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
LINE='include "/configs/projectname.conf"'
sed -n "\|$LINE|q;\$a $LINE" lighttpd.conf >> lighttpd.conf
```

Use the pipe as separator and quit if `$LINE` has been found. Otherwise, append `$LINE` at the end.

Since we only read the file in sed command, I suppose we have no clobber issue  in general (it depends on your shell settings).

Answer (score 1):

Using only `sed` I'd suggest the following solution:

```
sed -i \
    -e 's#^include "/configs/projectname.conf"#include "/configs/projectname.conf"#' \
    -e t \
    -e '$ainclude "/configs/projectname.conf"' lighttpd.conf
```

`s` replace the line `include "/configs/projectname.conf` with itself (using `#` as delimiter here)

`t` if the replacement was successful skip the rest of the commands

`$a` otherwise jump to the last line and append `include "/configs/projectname.conf` after it

Comment: use `-e T` if gnu sed is being used (instead of `-e t`)

Answer (score 0):

I elaborated on kev's grep/sed solution by setting variables in order to reduce duplication.

Set the variables in the first line (hint: `$_option` shall match everything on the line up until the value [including any seperator like = or :]).

```
_file="/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf" _option="mailhub=" _value="my.domain.tld" \
        sh -c '\
            grep -q "^$_option" "$_file" \
            && sed -i "s/^$_option.*/$_option$_value/" "$_file" \
            || echo "$_option$_value" >> "$_file"\
        '
```

Mind that the `sh -c '...'` just has the effect of widening the scope of the variables without the need for an `export`. (See [Setting an environment variable before a command in bash not working for second command in a pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856129/setting-an-environment-variable-before-a-command-in-bash-not-working-for-second))

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to find and search config changes:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Find and Replace config values
find_and_replace_config () {
   file=$1
   var=$2
   new_value=$3
   awk -v var="$var" -v new_val="$new_value" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="}match($1, "^\\s*" var "\\s*") {$2=" " new_val}1' "$file" > output.tmp && sudo mv output.tmp $file
}

find_and_replace_config /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini max_execution_time 60
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run this command using a **python script** within a Linux terminal...

```
import os,sys
LINE = 'include '+ <insert_line_STRING>
FILE = <insert_file_path_STRING>                                
os.system('grep -qxF $"'+LINE+'" '+FILE+' || echo $"'+LINE+'" >> '+FILE)
```

The $ and double quotations had me in a jungle, but this worked.
Thanks everyone

Answer (score -2):

I needed to edit a file with restricted write permissions so needed `sudo`. working from ghostdog74's answer and using a temp file:

```
awk 'FNR==NR && /configs.*projectname\.conf/{f=1;next}f==0;END{ if(!f) { print "your line"}} ' file > /tmp/file
sudo mv /tmp/file file
```

Comment: This doesn't look correct, it will lose the other lines from the file when the config line is missing.