# sed add line if not exists

Tags: sed

I need to make a change in the php.ini configuration file via `sed` (or similar).

I need to add the following text:

```
extension=solr.so
```

The line has to be added as line number 941 in the configuration file. However, if the file is already there, it should not be added again.

I guess there are two approaches: 1) replace line 941 with the text, or 2) search for the text and add it to line 941 if there are not matches.

I have the following command that works fine, except that the line is added again if the script is run again:

```
sed '941i\
extension=solr.so' /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini > /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

How can I make sure that this command does not add the line if it is already there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Appending a line to a file only if it does not already exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3557037/appending-a-line-to-a-file-only-if-it-does-not-already-exist)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The easiest way would be to test before using `grep`, for example:

```
grep -q -e 'extension=solr.so' file || sed '...'
```

Also, it is estrange that you need **exactly** that line. You should add it at the end, or something like that.

Also, note that taking the same file as input **and** output **never** should be done. This can damage the file badly. You should be using the `-i` sed parameter to do in-place editing.