# search and add the line if not present in shell

Tags: shell

I need to search a string in the file like

**abc.def.*, **

My input file looks like

```
mn.*, \
gh.*, \
pqrs.* \
fgh.* \
zcv.* \
rp.* \
```

My output has to be appended if the search string is not present in the file it has to be appended in the file like

```
mn.*, \
gh.*, \
abc.def.*, \
pqrs.* \
fgh.* \
zcv.* \
rp.* \
```

How do i do it in the shell script. I am able to search with grep with pattern but not able to add the line. Any quick suggestions would help me
Below is my command

```
grep -q -F "abc.def.*, \" filename
echo $?
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Appending a line to a file only if it does not already exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3557037/appending-a-line-to-a-file-only-if-it-does-not-already-exist)

Comment: It adds in last line if we do that.. But i want the line to be appended before 5 lines from the bottom.

Comment: @user1485267 : You need to specify in your question the precise rule, **where** to insert the new line, instead of just giving an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1,

```
grep -q -F 'abc.def.*, \' filename || tac filename|sed '4aabc.def.*, \\'|tac
```

If match the pattern `abc.def.*, \`, it will not execute the command after `||`, the first `tac` will reverse the file lines for append the pattern in 5th line by `sed '4a`, the last `tac` will restore the file lines.

2,

```
grep -q -F 'abc.def.*, \' filename || sed "$(( $( wc -l < filename) -4 )) a abc.def.*, \\\\" filename
```

Something as the case 1, but this will use `wc` to index the 5th line and append to that, `wc -l < filename` will only get the file lines number. The `\\\\` for escape and print `/` in double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

This bit of shell will add the line in question after the fifth from the bottom one if it's not already present in the file:

```sh
filename=input.txt
if ! grep -qF 'abc.def.*, \' "$filename"; then
    ed -s "$filename" <<'EOF'
$-4a
abc.def.*, \
.
w
EOF
fi
```

thanks to `ed` being easily able to set the current line marker to X lines before the last one.

Comment: Thanks Shawn, But i am looking with the one liner of the command which helps me to do add multiple lines in future. Thanks for your suggestions