# Modify Hosts file with echo

Tags: macos, bash, echo, sudo

I have two simple script that enables/disables Cisco AnyConnect when I don't want it trying to connect on each login/network transition. All was fine and dandy, but I wanted to add a line to the hosts file as well. The reason I'm using "echo $password | sudo -S" for most of the commands is because this script is being run from the script menu in Mac OS X. The terminal window does not open to address sudo password prompts.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Start_AnyConnect.command

password=`/usr/bin/osascript <<EOT
with timeout of (30 * 60) seconds
    tell application "Finder"
        activate
        set myReply to text returned of (display dialog "Enter your password to authorize AnyConnect startup script" default answer "" with hidden answer)
    end tell
end timeout
EOT`

echo $password | sudo -S echo -e "127.0.0.1\twpad.company.com" >> /etc/hosts
sleep 2

echo $password | sudo -S mv "/Library/LaunchAgents_Disabled/com.cisco.anyconnect.gui.plist" "/Library/LaunchAgents/com.cisco.anyconnect.gui.plist"
echo $password | sudo -S mv "/Library/LaunchDaemons_Disabled/com.cisco.anyconnect.vpnagentd.plist" "/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.cisco.anyconnect.vpnagentd.plist"
echo $password | sudo -S launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.cisco.anyconnect.vpnagentd.plist

sleep 5

open /Applications/Cisco/Cisco\ AnyConnect\ Secure\ Mobility\ Client.app

exit 0
```

The problem I'm having is that

```
echo $password | sudo -S echo -e "127.0.0.1\twpad.company.com" >> /etc/hosts
```

appends "`-e 127.0.0.1\twpad.company.com`" in stead of "`127.0.0.1     wpad.company.com`" to the hosts file.

If I run the following command by itself it works as expected:

```
sudo echo -e "127.0.0.1\twpad.company.com" >> /etc/hosts
```

Is there another way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: You don't have to use a tab as the white space in Unix host files. Replace it with a space and you shouldn't need the -e switch to echo.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84882/sudo-echo-something-etc-privilegedfile-doesnt-work-is-there-an-alterna) might help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit or create the file '/etc/hosts.ac' to add your desired host entries. When you start AnyConnect, that file will replace '/etc/hosts'.

No scripted appending will be needed.

Comment: I read the AnyConnect admin guide, but this gem eluded me. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me on OSX (last tested on Yosemite.) Hope it helps someone else!

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "127.0.0.1\twpad.company.com\n" >> /etc/hosts'
```

From the [Macworld forums](http://hints.macworld.com/comment.php?mode=view&cid=42301):

> The actual explanation is that sudo invokes a subshell as root, and passes only it's first arg to that subshell to run.
>
> Once the command finishes the subshell exits, and it's standard out is piped into >>. This attempts to open up and append to it's file argument as the original UID, which fails due to lack of privilege.
>
> So, the solution is to pass the entire command line, including any redirects, so the whole thing is passed to sudo as one arg.

Comment: this is good however this will not work if there is any variable inside the string.

Comment: Was looking for a solution for me that would do just that from the `docker exec` command line. Worked perfectly! Thanks.

`docker exec -it container_name sh -c 'echo "IP alias" >> /etc/hosts'`

Answer (score 5):

The version of `echo` that is being run doesn't support `-e`. When you use `sudo` you get `/bin/echo` rather than the shell's builtin `echo`. Use `printf` instead:

```
echo $password | sudo -S printf "127.0.0.1\twpad.company.com\n" >> /etc/hosts
```

Also, see the question linked to in Jaypal's comment regarding redirection and `sudo`.

Comment: to the question implied by the title "Modify Hosts file with echo" this one is the better answer :) +1