# Append line to /etc/hosts file with shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, sed

I have a new Ubuntu 12.04 VPS. I am trying to write a setup script that completes an entire LAMP installation. Where I am having trouble is appending a line to the `/etc/hosts` file. My current hosts file looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost Venus

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost Venus
192.241.xx.xx  venus.example.com venus

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

I have tried a variety of `sed` commands using the append (`\a`) command. For some reason Ubuntu either just echoes the contents of the `hosts` file in terminal or does nothing at all. How would I properly inject the second line into the file with a bash script?

Comment: https://github.com/alphabetum/hosts looks like a good solution if you are allowed to install packages

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Make sure to use the `-i` option of `sed`.

```
-i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
  edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)

sed -i "2i192.241.xx.xx  venus.example.com venus" /etc/hosts
```

Otherwise,

```
echo "192.241.xx.xx  venus.example.com venus" >> /etc/hosts
```

would append the line at the end of the file, which could work as you expect.

Comment: This assumes that the 127.0.0.1 line is the first line of the input stream (that the insert should be done on the second line). That is probably correct in many cases, but it bears mentioning.

Comment: -bash: /etc/hosts: Permission denied. Any ideas?

Comment: @Alex2php Make sure you have root access to modify that file.

Comment: This one solved for me: 
sudo -- sh -c "echo test >> /etc/hosts"

just sudo doesn't work if i try to append something…

Comment: Note that on Mac, you need to specify `-i ''`

such as `sed -i '' '2i192.241.11.22 venus.example.com venus' /etc/hosts`. The Mac version of sed requires the extension parameter for `-i`, even if it's empty.

Comment: With sed you should use `$ a` option to append to last line, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50003244/658497

Comment: why i have an error    sed: -e expression #1, char 3: unknown command: `.'
?

Comment: sed -i "$(awk '/^$/{print NR; exit}' /etc/hosts)i192.xxx.xxx  venus.example.com venus" /etc/hosts

Answer (score 51):

If your in mac or you need sudo permission to this try this:

```
sudo -- sh -c -e "echo '192.34.0.03   subdomain.domain.com' >> /etc/hosts";
```

It will still ask you for password.

alternative way from @kainjow

```
echo '192.34.0.03 subdomain.domain.com' | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts
```

Comment: You can also use `tee`: `echo '192.34.0.03   subdomain.domain.com' | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts`

Comment: This seems to be the case for ubuntu 16 too.

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for. I'd love to know what exactly `-- sh -c -e` does though? I prefer to know what I'm putting in my terminal rather than just copy pasting :)

Comment: You don't need `-e`

Comment: @powerbuoy The double tack `--` is used in shell commands to signify the end of command options, after which only positional parameters are accepted. The `sh` is the shell command interpreter used with the flag `-c` which causes the commands to be read from the string operand instead of from the standard input. The `-e` flag is unnecessary for our use case, but it causes the interpreted command to exit immediately if any untested command fails in non-interactive mode.

Comment: ! beware, this would completely overwrite your `hosts` file. make sure you backup your `hosts` file before proceeding with `tee`. Backup the file like `sudo cp /etc/hosts /etc/hosts.bak`.

Answer (score 38):

#### Insert/Update Entry

If you want to programmatically insert/update a hosts entry using bash, here's a script I wrote to do that:

```
#!/bin/bash

# insert/update hosts entry
ip_address="192.168.x.x"
host_name="my.hostname.example.com"
# find existing instances in the host file and save the line numbers
matches_in_hosts="$(grep -n $host_name /etc/hosts | cut -f1 -d:)"
host_entry="${ip_address} ${host_name}"

echo "Please enter your password if requested."

if [ ! -z "$matches_in_hosts" ]
then
    echo "Updating existing hosts entry."
    # iterate over the line numbers on which matches were found
    while read -r line_number; do
        # replace the text of each line with the desired host entry
        sudo sed -i '' "${line_number}s/.*/${host_entry} /" /etc/hosts
    done <<< "$matches_in_hosts"
else
    echo "Adding new hosts entry."
    echo "$host_entry" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts > /dev/null
fi
```

The script is intended for use with OS X but would work on linux as well with minor tweaking.

Comment: too complex script to add just a line

Comment: This is a better solution to just adding a line to etc/hosts imo

Comment: this is perfect, although update part is not working as expected, it still continued adding the line even if the ipaddress and hostname combination existed. also did a little tweak so that instead of hardcoding the script will take ipaddress and host name as an argument.

Comment: Great, thanks! Just changed the grep regex slightly to `grep -n "^[^#]*${host_name}" /etc/hosts` to also ignore potential matches in commented lines

Answer (score 5):

```
echo "127.0.0.1 localhost `hostname`">./temp_hosts
echo "192.241.xx.xx  venus.example.com">>./temp_hosts
cat /etc/hosts |tail -n +2 >>./temp_hosts
cat ./temp_hosts > /etc/hosts
rm ./temp_file
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, Vladimir. I will test your method as well and post if it worked for me to benefit any future visitors to this question.

Comment: @Ingo Do you really think it's appropriate to suggest that someone *not* try something (assuming that thing is not dangerous)? Let the man experiment!

Answer (score 2):

I should point out that `sed` (the *stream* editor) is not actually intended for editing files, although it can be used to do that. ([Standard sed](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) doesn't have a built-in mechanism for writing to other than standard output.) A more appropriate tool would be [`ed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ed.html).

The following ed script says "find the line containing the (admittedly sloppy) regular expression /127.0.0.1/ and append at the next line." (The lone period tells ed to stop appending.)

```
ed /etc/hosts <<-'EOF'
    /127.0.0.1/a
    192.241.xx.xx  venus.example.com
    .
    wq
EOF
```

That said, you can really just append this line to the *end* of your /etc/hosts file very trivially:

```
echo '192.241.xx.xx  venus.example.com' >> /etc/hosts
```

Comment: I've never used `ed` before. It seems very powerful and will come in handy. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: For some users, depending on their permissions setup, you may need to `sudo -- sh -c "echo '192.241.xx.xx  venus.example.com' >> /etc/hosts"` as simply `sudo echo ...` will result in a `permission denied`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `sed`, like:

```
sed '/Venus/ a\  
192.241.xx.xx  venus.example.com venus' /etc/hosts
```

Answer (score 0):

I've developed a user-friendly script for easily adding, removing, and listing IP addresses and hostnames in the host file:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Created by Mohamad Hamouday
# Date: 2023-12-05
# Purpose: A script to add, remove, and list entries in the hosts file


# Function to add an entry to the hosts file
add_entry() {
    # Get user input for IP address and server name
    read -p "Enter IP address: " ip_address
    read -p "Enter server name: " server_name

    # Check if the input is not empty
    if [ -z "$ip_address" ] || [ -z "$server_name" ]; then
        echo "IP address and server name cannot be empty."
        exit 1
    fi

    # Append the entry to the hosts file
    echo "$ip_address $server_name" >> /etc/hosts

    echo "Entry added to /etc/hosts: $ip_address $server_name"
}

# Function to remove an entry from the hosts file
remove_entry() {
    # Get user input for IP address or server name to remove
    read -p "Enter IP address or server name to remove: " entry_to_remove

    # Check if the input is not empty
    if [ -z "$entry_to_remove" ]; then
        echo "Entry cannot be empty."
        exit 1
    fi

    # Check if the entry exists in the hosts file
    if grep -q "$entry_to_remove" /etc/hosts; then
        # Remove the entry from the hosts file using sed
        sed -i.bak -e "/$entry_to_remove/d" /etc/hosts

        echo "Entry removed from /etc/hosts: $entry_to_remove"
    else
        echo "Entry does not exist in /etc/hosts: $entry_to_remove"
    fi
}


# Function to list all active entries in the hosts file
list_entries() {
    echo "Non-commented entries in /etc/hosts:"
    grep -E -v '^\s*#' /etc/hosts
}


# Check if the script is executed with root privileges
if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
   echo "This script must be run as root."
   exit 1
fi

# Display menu for user choice
echo "1. Add entry"
echo "2. Remove entry"
echo "3. List entries"
read -p "Enter your choice (1, 2, or 3): " choice

case $choice in
    1)
        add_entry
        ;;
    2)
        remove_entry
        ;;
    3)
        list_entries
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Invalid choice. Exiting."
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

To execute it just run:

```
sudo sh scriptname.sh
```

Answer (score -2):

try this with root access.

```
 public void edithost() {
    sudo("echo " + "192.168.43.1     www.openrap.com openrap" + " >> /etc/hosts");
    sudo("echo " + "192.168.43.1  openrap.com openrap" + " >> /etc/hosts");
    sudo("echo " + "192.168.2.144  www.openrap.com openrap" + " >> /etc/hosts");
    sudo("echo " + "192.168.2.144  openrap.com openrap" + " >> /etc/hosts");
}
```

sudo for super user permission

```
public static void sudo(String... strings) {
    try {
        Process su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(su.getOutputStream());

        for (String s : strings) {
            outputStream.writeBytes(s + "\n");
            outputStream.flush();
        }

        outputStream.writeBytes("exit\n");
        outputStream.flush();
        try {
            su.waitFor();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

this will append the lines to hosts in the android