# python3 - subprocess with sudo to >> append to /etc/hosts

Tags: python, subprocess

I've been wrestling with solutions from "[How do I use sudo to redirect output to a location I don't have permission to write to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82256/how-do-i-use-sudo-to-redirect-output-to-a-location-i-dont-have-permission-to-wr)" and "[append line to /etc/hosts file with shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339248/append-line-to-etc-hosts-file-with-shell-script)" with no luck.

I want to "append 10.10.10.10 puppetmaster" at the end of /etc/hosts. (Oracle/Red-Hat linux).

Been trying variations of:

```
subprocess.call("sudo -s", shell=True)

subprocess.call('sudo sh -c" "10.10.10.10 puppetmaster" >> /etc/hosts"', shell=True)

subprocess.call(" sed -i '10.10.10.10 puppetmaster' /etc/hosts", shell=True)
```

But /etc/hosts file stands still.
Can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: why don't you just append to the file using python?

Comment: I'm frankly new to python (coming from java background). There's a way to use python to append without invoking bash shell? I shall look this up. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it just means running the script with sudo, I added the code it is two lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in python quite easily once you run the script with sudo:

```
with open("/etc/hosts","a") as f:
    f.write('10.10.10.10 puppetmaster\n')
```

opening with `a` will append.

Comment: Does the OP want to escalate privileges of the entire script? We don't know if parts of it handle untrusted data or the like.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, if the OP is the one writing the script what is going to happen?

Comment: I'm planning on doing  "sudo ./script" or as root

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, that depends on what else the script does :)

Comment: @SndLt, then you don't need to use `sudo` *inside* the script at all.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, we just got the answer :)

Comment: Basically, I'm writing a script to use python to automate puppet agent initiation on a oracle linux/redhat. Is it an ok practice (in terms of efficiency and security) to run the code as root from start?

Comment: BTW, aren't you missing a newline here?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, indeed I was

Comment: @SndLt, that depends on the code and what it does (including the parts not shown here). If it doesn't handle any untrusted data, though, go right ahead and run it as root the whole way through.

Comment: @SndLt, what Charles said.

Comment: @SndLt: The best practice is to drop the privileges as soon as possible (to make the attack surface less). But you could choose for yourself the tradeoffs between security and convenience in your particular case.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `dd`:

```
subprocess.Popen(['sudo', 'dd', 'if=/dev/stdin',
    'of=/etc/hosts', 'conv=notrunc', 'oflag=append'],
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE).communicate("10.10.10.10 puppetmaster\n")
```

Comment: Nice! No shells at all.

Comment: ...though unnecessary, since the OP is running the script as root, so they can just open the output file for append directly, without needing `sudo` at all.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing lies within the scope of the `sudo`.

The code you are trying calls `sudo` with the arguments `sh` and `-c" "10.10.10.10 puppetmaster"`.  The redirection of the `>>` operator, however, is done by the surrounding shell, of course with its permissions.

To achieve the effect you want, try starting a shell using sudo which then is given the command:

```
sudo bash -c 'sh -c" "10.10.10.10 puppetmaster" >> /etc/hosts"'
```

This will do the trick because the `bash` you started with `sudo` has superuser permissions and thus will not fail when it tries to perform the output redirection with `>>`.

To do this from within Python, use this:

```
subprocess.call("""sudo bash -c 'sh -c" "10.10.10.10 puppetmaster" >> /etc/hosts"'""", shell=True)
```

But of course, if you run your Python script with superuser permissions (start it with `sudo`) already, all this isn't necessary and the original code will work (without the additional `sudo` in the `call`):

```
subprocess.call('sh -c" "10.10.10.10 puppetmaster" >> /etc/hosts"', shell=True)
```

Comment: This seems... rather unnecessarily complex and error-prone, compared to a `shell=False` version with only a single shell run as a subprocess to `sudo`.

Comment: You are right.  I mostly explained the `sudo` with `>>` effect and how to deal with it in general.  The concrete situation cries for simpler solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you weren't escalating privileges for the entire script, I'd recommend the following:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['sudo', 'tee', '-a', '/etc/hosts'],
                     stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
p.stdin.write(b'10.10.10.10 puppetmaster\n')
p.stdin.close()
p.wait()
```

Then you can write arbitrary content to the process's stdin (`p.stdin`).

Comment: "sudo ./charles.py" leads to {Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./charles.py", line 8, in <module>
    p.stdin.write('10.10.10.10 puppetmaster\n')
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'} am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @SndLt: `subprocess` uses bytes by default. Use bytes literals: `b'10...'`. btw, you could use `p.communicate(b'10.10.10.10 puppetmaster\n')` instead of the last 3 lines in the code example. Also, use `stdout=DEVNULL` (it seems you are on Python 3) and you don't need `shell=False` (it is default).

Comment: @SndLt, ...what J.F. Sebastian said. The only thing you did wrong was not clearly specifying in your question that this was Python 3 rather than Python 2.

Comment: @Charles Duffy , I see. So if I want to run this stdin in python3,  just set stdout to null? or use p.communicate instead of last 3 lines? Thanks.

Comment: @SndLt, well, the last three lines will work otherwise as-is if you make the string a bytestring rather than a Unicode string, _or_ you can use `communicate()`. (Might need a bytestring there too; I'd need to check the docs -- like most of the Real World writing commercial software, I'm still on Python 2).

Comment: @SndLt, ...the `DEVNULL` constant is an efficiency, portability and terseness improvement, not a correctness one (on UNIX).

Comment: p.communicate works!! I also edited the title of post to pytrhon3. In the future,  I'll keep that version in mind. Thanks.