# Why can't I echo contents into a new file as sudo?

Tags: bash, echo, sudo

I came across this weird problem just now and I can't seem to get to the bottom of it. I'm trying to add a config file to /etc/sudoers.d/ but get permission denied.  In the example below, the file "tweedle" doesn't exist and:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4.0K Jan  2 18:27 sudoers.d/
```

So here's the command:

```
$ sudo echo "tweedle ALL=(ALL) ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/tweedle
-bash: /etc/sudoers.d/tweedle: Permission denied
```

It doesn't even work when I break it into two commands:

```
$ sudo touch /etc/sudoers.d/tweedle
$ sudo echo "poodle" > /etc/sudoers.d/tweedle
```

When I tested it locally, same problem:

```
$ cd ~
$ mkdir -m 755 tweedle
$ sudo chown root:root tweedle
$ sudo echo "battle" > ~/tweedle/beetle
-bash: /home/spanky/tweedle/beetle: Permission denied
$ sudo touch tweedle/beetle
$ sudo echo "battle" > tweedle/beetle
-bash: tweedle/beetle: Permission denied
```

Without sudo, all is well:

```
$ cd ~
$ mkdir poodle
$ echo "noodle" > poodle/bottle
$ cat poodle/bottle
noodle
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Quite correct, although searching did not get me there. Thanks.

Comment: What you are telling the shell is "Run sudo ...; the output from that command please write to the end of `sudoers`. Note that the writing is done *outside* of the command executed by `sudo`, with your privileges (i.e., not allowed to write that file). There should be a command like `visudo(1)` available to edit the file securely.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84882/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `echo` command is being run as `root`, but the redirection is done by your shell, so it's executed as the current user, not as `root`.

The simplest solution is to invoke a root shell to run both the command and the redirection.

Rather than:

```
sudo echo line > file
```

try this:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo line > file'
```

or

```
sudo bash -c 'echo line > file'
```

Comment: Dude, "The echo command is being run as root, but the redirection is done by your shell, so it's executed as the current user, not as root." -- that just saved the day here, thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

The answer is to use "tee" with a pipe, a command I wasn't familiar with, so you can use sudo for the second half:

```
$ echo "tweedle ALL=(ALL) ALL" | sudo tee /etc/sudoers.d/tweedle
```

Comment: an interesting workaround but @Keith's answer is way more idiomatic

Comment: I'm building up a lot of lines in a shell script string variable which I then append to a file. This method saves me from figuring out how to expand that variable in the argument to sh -c .