# Add lines to /etc/hosts file

Tags: bash, sed, hosts

I have RHEL and i wish to run a shell script that will add several lines (over 10 lines) to the /etc/hosts file. 
I tried to use

```
sed -i "10.161.61.111 acr111" /etc/hosts 
sed -i "10.161.61.110 acr110" /etc/hosts
```

and so on, but i get

> sed: -e expression #1, char 3: unknown command: `.'

Any idea how to fix this? 
Or maybe another way to run sh file which will add hosts to the hosts file? 
Thanks,

Comment: Where do the extra data come from?  File? Variable? data in the script?

Comment: @Maya, you can add new entry to /etc/hosts with `sed -i` and `$ a` option, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50003244/658497

Answer (score 3):

Have you read the man page for sed? You're not using the -i parameter correctly.

Instead, why don't you just use:

```
echo "10.161.61.111 acr111" >> /etc/hosts
echo "10.161.61.110 acr110" >> /etc/hosts
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) to append (`>>`) multiple lines to `/etc/fstab`:

```
cat << EOF >> /etc/fstab
10.161.61.111 acr111
10.161.61.110 acr110
10.161.61.109 acr109
10.161.61.108 acr108
EOF
```

Answer (score 2):

If data comes from a file do:

```
cat newdata >> /etc/hosts
```

If data comes from a variable:

```
echo "$newdata" >> /etc/host
```

Answer (score 2):

You most include -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX] as follow

sed -i "**3i**10.161.61.111 acr111" /etc/hosts

**ni** is the line number where the text will be appen