# can't echo in terminal "bash: /etc/odbcinst.ini: Permission denied"

Tags: python, bash, shell

I have a large setup program that saves hours and hours when I spin up a new machine, but I cannot get one thing to work right now. I want to fill a TD driver required config file, and since it is a special protected file I'm getting a hassle. My python looks like:

```
#configure webapi driver
ODBC_PATH       = os.path.join(HOMEPATH, '/etc/odbcinst.ini')
ODBC_SETTINGS   = """\
[FreeTDS]
Description = TD Driver (MSSQL)
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
FileUsage = 1"""

call_sp('sudo echo "{}" > {}'.format(ODBC_SETTINGS, ODBC_PATH))
```

where `call_sp` is just my way of calling a subprocess but allowing args, like Popen does. I was clueless, because it's failing silently (I don't know till I try to run server) and in the shell I don't get prompted for my pw:

```
cchilders:~/scripts/setup_scripts/dimensional [master]$ sudo echo "[FreeTDS]
Description = TD Driver (MSSQL)
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
FileUsage = 1" > /etc/odbcinst.ini 
bash: /etc/odbcinst.ini: Permission denied


cchilders:~/scripts/setup_scripts [master]$ sudo echo "somethin" > /etc/odbcinst.ini 
bash: /etc/odbcinst.ini: Permission denied
```

but sudoing into nano works and I can do it manually:

```
cchilders:~/scripts/setup_scripts [master]$ sudo nano /etc/odbcinst.ini 
[sudo] password for cchilders:
```

Why can't I fill this ini file with text from terminal, and if it isn't possible, how can I automatically fill in python script? Ty

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84882/sudo-echo-something-etc-privilegedfile-doesnt-work-is-there-an-alterna. In short, please try `sudo sh -c "echo 'something' > /etc/odbcinst.ini"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is essentially a duplicate of this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84882/sudo-echo-something-etc-privilegedfile-doesnt-work-is-there-an-alterna).

Have you tried using tee instead?

```
$ echo '{}' | sudo tee --append //etc/odbcinst.ini
```