# echo to an existing file

Tags: android, linux, bash, busybox

When I try to `echo` via my script to an existing file, the script doesn't recognize the existing file and creates a duplicate file on Android.

This is the input code in script:

```
>echo "Hello" > /system/etc/new
```

This is the output in terminal for:

```
>cat /system/etc/new
```

> /system/etc/new: No such file or directory

Comment: do an (ls /system/etc) -- do you see any files listed or do you get an error??

Comment: Are you running as the root user? Otherwise you cannot write to /system.  You can have the top of the script basically call "su -c ....." before running

Comment: ls in the directory does show the file,Yes I am running as root and mounted system read-write , just that the file created by script is not recognised by terminal

Answer (score 1):

Are you not experiencing:

> Permission denied

At any rate,

```
echo "Hello" > /system/etc/new
```

is not allowed to write into `/system/etc/`.

Likely answered on https://stackoverflow.com/a/550808/218152.

Comment: Nothing of that sort , System is mounted rw , but file will get duplicated and original one cannot be recognised

Comment: Can you develop on *duplicated*? Does the old file get renamed somehow? If so, to what? What does `ls -al /system/etc/new*` return?