# Changing msg_max size on Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I was trying to change the msg_max queue size on my ubuntu 14.04 system. Here is the console output:

```
$ sudo echo 500 > /proc/sys/fs/mqueue/msg_max
-bash: /proc/sys/fs/mqueue/msg_max: Permission denied

$
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/mqueue/msg_max
1000

$ sudo echo 500 > /proc/sys/fs/mqueue/msg_max
-bash: /proc/sys/fs/mqueue/msg_max: Permission denied

$ sudo sh -c "echo 500 > /proc/sys/fs/mqueue/msg_max"
[sudo] password for XXX:

$ cat /proc/sys/fs/mqueue/msg_max
500
```

My question is why the first approach using **echo** directly is not working while the other one using **sh -c** works?

Comment: From the target duplicate: _The problem is that the shell does output redirection, not sudo or echo, so this is being done as your regular user_.

Comment: thanks got the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84882/sudo-echo-something-etc-.privilegedfile-doesnt-work-is-there-an-alterna