# Create file with content in one line of bash

Tags: bash

I wish to create a single file with some contents known to me.

How do I do this in couple lines of bash?

this command will be used inside of a single script, so it should create file, add text, save, and quit automatically by itself without human intervention.

I know that

```
cat >> some.text
type some stuff
ctrl + D
```

will work. But is there a pure command line way of doing it?

Thanks

Comment: I presume you are aware that `cat >> some.txt` will **append** to whatever is already in the file - try running it twice. If you want to overwrite, use a single `>`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell THanks! good to know!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use a "here document":

```
cat >> some.text << 'END'
some stuff here
more stuff
END
```

The delimiter (here `END`) is an arbitrary word. Quoting this delimiter after the `<<` will ensure that no expansion is performed on the contents.

Answer (score 8):

You could also do the following:
`echo 'some stuff' > your/file.txt`

For multiline, here's another example:
`printf "some stuff\nmore stuff" >> your/file.txt`

Comment: Updated my answer for multiline.

Answer (score 3):

For making it multiline its also possilbe to echo in "execution mode":

```
echo -e "line1\nline2" > /tmp/file
```

so the \n will make a carriage return.

Answer (score 1):

Great answer from @that-other-guy, also important to note that you can include the directory of the file in there and not to forget your bin/bash stuff at the start, and that it works for more than just text files.
See below my example for yaml files. And remember to make your bash files executable after with: chmod u+x fileName.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

cat >> ~/dir/newDir/yamlFiles/testing.yaml << 'END'
service:
  - testing
testing:
  setOpts:
    podCount: 2
END
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need sudo to write the file, `sudo echo "text" > file` won't work.

Use this to overwrite the file

```
echo "text" | sudo tee file > /dev/null
```

and this to append:

```
echo "text" | sudo tee --append file > /dev/null
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84882/sudo-echo-something-etc-privilegedfile-doesnt-work).