# Why file is not created as owned by a specific user i designated

Tags: linux, bash

I have a php script that will collection data and write log into a file, the directory belongs to an user called 'ingestion' and a group called 'ingestion'. I was using the command

```
sudo -u ingestion php [script] &>> /var/log/FOLDER/adapter.log
```

The owner and group of FOLDER is ingestion. However, the created adapter.log still belongs to root user and root group, how is this possible?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4830/how-do-i-use-redirection-with-sudo 
 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/84899/635608 - the redirection is done by the shell before it starts the program (sudo in this case)

Comment: The shell get tha tline and process it step by step. One of the first things is to open the output file (as the real user calling), then it executes `sudo`, whose output has already been redirected, and runs the `php` process as the designated user. In other words: `sudo` is affecting the command being run, but the redirection is never seen by `sudo` but by the calling shell, who is the one that takes care of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is created by the bash running as root, not by the process that you run via sudo as ingestion.

That's because the `>> foo` is part of the command line, not of the process started by sudo.

Here:

```
#foo.sh
echo foo: `id -u`
```

Then:

```
tmp root# sudo -u peter bash foo.sh > foo
tmp root# ls -l foo
-rw-------  1 root  staff  9 Mar  2 18:52 foo
tmp root# cat foo
foo: 501
```

You can see that the file is created as root but the foo.sh script is run as uid 501.

You can fix this by running e.g.:

```
tmp root# sudo -u peter bash -c "bash foo.sh > foo"
tmp root# ls -l foo
-rw-------  1 peter  staff  9 Mar  2 18:54 foo
tmp root# cat foo
foo: 501
```

In your case, of course, replace `"..."` with your php command.

Comment: You mean replace "bash foo.sh" with my php command, right? Thanks for you answer!

Comment: One more question, i was trying something like
```
# sudo -u peter bash  "php foo.php > foo" 
which give me a permission denied, do you know why this doesn't work?
```

Comment: Perhaps when you sudo'ed as root you changed directory to somewhere your unprivileged user cannot write? I suppose you didn't really use 'peter' but your own :-D