# define environment variable in databricks init script

Tags: python, bash, azure, pyspark, azure-databricks

I want to define an environment variable in Databricks init script and then read it in Pyspark notebook.
I wrote this:

```
    dbutils.fs.put("/databricks/scripts/initscript.sh","""
#!/bin/bash
export env="dev"
pip install pretty-html-table==0.9.14
""", True)
```

the pyspark code:

```
import os
environment=os.getenv("env")
```

it gives:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
```

but the Pyspark notebook is not able to read the environment variable properly

Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: Why not define it on the cluster level instead? then it will be propagated everywhere

Comment: @AlexOtt what if you have multiple clusters, but want a global environment variable set? Further, any time a new cluster is made, you don't want people to have to remember to add the environment variable via the Spark configs tab in Advanced Options every time they create a new cluster

Comment: one way to achieve this is to use cluster policies... But have you tried to use the existing answer ?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use normal `export` since then the variable will only be available to the init script subprocess.

Instead, use the following line in an init script to set an environment variable globally:

```
echo AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_HERE >> /etc/environment
```

This will write to the `environment` file of the cluster, which is read from any subprocess on the cluster.

In case you need admin permissions to edit the target file, you can use this instead:

```
echo AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_HERE | sudo tee -a /etc/environment
```

Comment: What sudo is supposed to do?

Comment: Sudo gives you admin rights to edit this file. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo

Comment: Sudo does not work with redirections so what is it supposed to do in this context?

Comment: @jikuja I wasn't aware about that, please check my edited answer based on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84882/sudo-echo-something-etc-privilegedfile-doesnt-work