# How to empty ("truncate") a file on linux that already exists and is protected in someway?

Tags: linux, file, command-line

I have a file called error.log on my server that I need to frequently truncate. I have rw permissions for the file. Opening the file in vi > deleting all content > saving works (obviously). But when I try the below

```
cat /dev/null > error.log
```

I get the message

```
File already exists.
```

Obviously there is some kind of configuration done on the server to prevent accidental overriding of files. Can anybody tell how do I "truncate" the file in a single command?

Comment: For a non-protected file truncate -s 0 file works.

Answer (score 162, accepted):

You have the `noclobber` option set.  The error looks like it's from csh, so you would do:

```
cat /dev/null >! file
```

If I'm wrong and you are using bash, you should do:

```
cat /dev/null >| file
```

in bash, you can also shorten that to:

```
>| file
```

Comment: you are right about the shell being csh. How did you know that?

Comment: @Wikidkaka - based on the error message.  csh on my system gives the similar `File exists` error while bash gives the very different `cannot overwrite existing file` error.

Comment: @Jarmund - because the user has noclobber set, `>file` does not work.

Comment: What's the difference between `> file` and `>| file`?

Comment: @Will - if you have the `noclobber` option set, trying to redirect to an existing file fails. To override for the specific redirection while leaving noclobber on, you can use `>|`

Answer (score 76):

You can also use function **truncate**

```
$truncate -s0 yourfile
```

if permission denied, use sudo

```
$sudo truncate -s0 yourfile
```

Help/Manual: **man truncate**

tested on ubuntu Linux

Comment: truncate also touches the file's modification time - while ">file" does not touch if if the file is unchanged.

Comment: It doesn't release the disk space that file holds. At first it shows the 0 bytes. But when you write something to that file, the file size is = before truncate + new data size.

Comment: @AniketKulkarni that's because your file has not been opened with APPEND flag, so it keeps the write buffer, and when it updates that buffer it flushes the whole buffer to the file, and that's how you see it with the same + increased size.

Answer (score 48):

This will be enough to set the file size to 0:

```
> error.log
```

Comment: actually, this **doesn't** work with noclobber (tested it myself), so it's NOT a valid solution in this case ("-bash: error.log: cannot overwrite existing file"); see commend above ("@Jarmund - because the user has noclobber set, >file does not work."). I'm just wondering what kind of "intelligent people" upvote obviously wrong answers like this...

Answer (score 13):

the credit goes for my senior colleague for this:

```
:> filename
```

This will not break log files, so you can even use it on syslog, for example.

Comment: Please explain. How does it work? What is that notation doing?

Comment: @user31986 `:` is a no-effect command (almost a comment), then `>` is redirection as usual, thus this just redirects the lack of output from a command that does nothing into the file. If noclobber is enabled, you need `:>| filename` (bash) (and I presume `:>! filename` in csh assuming csh has `:`).

Answer (score 4):

> false|tee fileToTruncate

may work as well

Comment: That's just silly.  Or if this is useful, obscurely getting `dd` to output nothing would be even better than the plain readable `false`?

Answer (score 4):

Since sudo will not work with [redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82256/how-do-i-use-sudo-to-redirect-output-to-a-location-i-dont-have-permission-to-wr) `>`, I like the `tee` command for this purpose

```
echo "" | sudo tee fileName
```

Comment: well, actually it does, as described in both the question you linked and here above. "sudo sh -c '> error.log'"...

Comment: it depends on the permissions on the target file `error.log`, if that is already writable there is not need to sudo. I think the other issue is you are passing command as string argument to `sh` , I don't know how that is handled internally but that is another layer of complexity/redirection added

Comment: This won't actually truncate the file, because `echo ""` will add a newline. You can use `echo -n ""` to suppress the newline

Answer (score 2):

Any one can try this command to truncate any file in **linux system**

This will surely work in any format :

```
truncate -s 0 file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I do like this:
`cp /dev/null file`

Answer (score -4):

You can try also:

`echo -n > /my/file`

Comment: See the answer with a ton of votes? Try reading it, and look up `noclobber` and then ask yourself if your answer makes any sense at all.