# Unix shell script to truncate a large file

Tags: bash, shell, truncate

I am trying to write a Unix script which will truncate/empty a file which is continuously being written/open by an application when it reaches say 3GB of space. I know that the below command would do it :

```
cp /dev/null [filename]
```

But I am going to run this in an production environment automatically as a cron job - just posting here to see if you guys faced any issues while doing something similar to this.

Comment: These are prod. logs don't have value? I was fortunate to keep my production logs for a year+ (in bzip2 -9 fmt) and had a few small utilities that made it easy to extract job runtimes, records processed, and when loaded into a spreadsheet was easy to calculate and graph loading ratios and a bunch of stuff. We discovered a hdwr problem because of falling load-ratios. Yes, there are lovely monitoring tools out there, so it all depends on your situation. AS A SEPARATE OPTION, have you looked at `logrotate`, it might provide you some value (but be annoying with setting it up (just guessing)!).

Comment: Note that if the log file is opened with the O_APPEND flag, then truncation is effective.  If it is not opened with the O_APPEND flag, then the program will continue writing at offset 3 GiB (the first time); the system will treat the first 3 GiB as all-bytes-zero (which compresses well), but the file will continue to grow.  It all depends on the program writing the log.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to empty ("truncate") a file on linux that already exists and is protected in someway?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423281/how-to-empty-truncate-a-file-on-linux-that-already-exists-and-is-protected-i)

Answer (score 128):

Just to add another answer,

```
: > filename
```

`:` is a no-op in bash (POSIX-compliant), so this essentially just opens the file for writing (which of course truncates the file) and then immediately closes it.

EDIT: as shellter commented, you don't actually need a command to go along with the redirection:

```
$ echo foo > foo.txt
$ cat foo.txt
foo
$ > foo.txt
$ cat foo.txt
$
```

A simple redirection all by itself will clear the file.

Comment: @shellter make that an answer.

Comment: @antik : thanks, but see my comment to O.P. As a general rule, I'm against discarding production logs until they've been mined of any useful information. It's not clear if the O.P. is doing that (or, I'll admit, may not need to do it). Thanks and good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter - I *should* have known :) `exec > filename` was the first thing that popped into my head, and then I was fixated on the idea that there had to be some command to go with the redirection.

Comment: @shelter "$ > file" not POSIX and not portable. You should use the ":" no-op command before redirecting, as initially suggested.

Comment: +plus for smiley face

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @cardil, maybe it will help me remember this! :>)

Comment: As @AaronToponce poined out, "$ > file" is indeed not portable; on my Zsh setup it makes the shell hang (supposedly waiting for input). "$ : > file" works in Zsh just fine.

Comment: @opert Not quite.  The POSIX spec says "[i]f there is no command name, any redirections shall be performed in a subshell environment; it is unspecified whether this subshell environment is the same one as that used for a command substitution within the command." `zsh`, on the other hand, treats `> file` something like `cat > file` by default. Like most non-standard features of `zsh`, there are various options to modify the behavior. Setting `SH_NULLCMD` causes `zsh` to behave like the POSIX shell (`: > file`) instead.

Comment: @chepner Thank you for clarifying, although the POSIX language isn't crystal clear to me atm. I dug up the manpages and indeed Zsh treats `> file` like `cat > file`; see `man zshmisc` under the heading `REDIRECTIONS WITH NO COMMAND`. I read the POSIX spec you quoted to mean that the subshell environment is not defined precisely (the last phrase "within the command" hurts my brain).

Comment: Seriously; that's why I pasted a direct quote rather than trying to paraphrase. I'm not sure what distinction is being drawn in that sentence.

Comment: Does it take a lock while truncating? In our case we have a java process continuously writing to the file and the shell command is expected to truncate the file. Will there be any contentions?

Comment: @TechEnthusiast It depends on your expectation. The truncation itself is atomic, but you don't really know when it will happen relative to any particular write. You could, for example, wind up with a partial line at the beginning of the file.

Comment: @chepner Would there be a chance where the other process errors out while writing while truncate process is truncating. Are the operations serializable?

Comment: The operations are serialized at the file system level, but writes are not necessarily atomic whereas truncations are. For example, if one process does `echo "foo bar"` and another processes truncates the file, you might have 3 operations `write "foo "`, `truncate`, and `write "bar"`. (With such a small write the odds of it being split up are small, but not zero. The truncation, however, is guaranteed to be a single, uninterruptible operation.)

Comment: the redirection command does not stop but has to be terminated with ctrl-c

Comment: The redirection is not a command; it's an *instruction* to the shell to open a file for the actual command to use for standard input. Whether or not that command blocks indefinitely waiting for input from the file determines if you need to terminate it (via ctrl-c or any other method).

Answer (score 68):

I've used the following command on debian

```
truncate -s 0 filename
```

Comment: @SteveClay: `sudo sh -c ': > filename'` will also truncate `filename`

Comment: @SteveClay The OPs suggestion also works flawlessly with `sudo`: `sudo cp /dev/null filename`.  Also `cp` is portable while `truncate` is modern Linux only.

Answer (score 12):

That seems reasonable to me.  Unix, of course, would let you do this about 50 different ways.  Here are two examples:

```
echo -n "" >filename
cat /dev/null >filename
```

Comment: Maybe the first line is fine and enough for truncating the file.

Comment: @Timo - agreed. Edited my response for clarity.

Answer (score 3):

`trunc filename`

works on AIX flavor of UNIX

Answer (score 0):

There is an other alternative:

`dd count=0 of=filename`

The advantages (mainly useful for embedded systems):

- It does not need to spawn shell (bash, dash etc.) because no redirection
- Compatible to busybox

Comment: What is the dd tool exactly?

Comment: "man dd" tells "dd - convert and copy a file".
This tool comes from either GNU coreutils or busybox. Probably always in all the linux distribution and even android/toybox.