# Difference between Mac OS X and Linux scripting

Tags: macos, bash, csh

I have a script like this:

```
csh bbox.csh plt >! plt_P1.ps
```

The guy who wrote it used Darwin, but I am on Ubuntu 14.04. How to change it?
What does `>!` mean?

Comment: See also: [How to empty (“truncate”) a file on linux that already exists and is protected in someway?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423281/how-to-empty-truncate-a-file-on-linux-that-already-exists-and-is-protected-i).