# sudo doesn't work when redirecting the output of sed to a file

Tags: shell, unix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I use sudo to redirect output to a location I don’t have permission to write to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82256/how-do-i-use-sudo-to-redirect-output-to-a-location-i-dont-have-permission-to-wr)

Let's say I want to change a file "foo" that lives in /home, applying some regular expression to it (via **sed**), and put the result in a file called /home/foo2.

I don't have read/write access neither to /home or to foo, so then I use **sudo**. However, I still get a permission denied

```
sudo sed "s/bar/baz/" <foo >foo2
bash: foo2: Permission denied
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: You run into the problem because the shell does the I/O redirection before launching `sudo`, so it does the redirection with your own privileges, which you know aren't enough.  Therefore, to get it to work, you have to get the program run by `sudo` to do the I/O redirection.  Both answers that I see achieve that result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the in place option, `-i`.  Your syntax would be:

```
sed -i [pattern] filename
```

Comment: -i is for reading the file, I'm getting a permission denied for writing it

Comment: oh oh! it turns out -i is for reading and writing in the same file, awesome thanks

Comment: (but then I had to do first sudo cp foo foo2)

Comment: I should have mentioned that I suspected you were running into issues reading and writing to/from the same file at the same time and that your issue was related to that instead of being a file permission issue.

Comment: well, thing is, in the command I wrote I had a typo: I wrote ">foo <foo" instead of ">foo2 <foo", so I guess that's why you were confused :)

Answer (score 1):

Although `sh` might be a bad idea in general, this will give permission to create a new file `foo2` for your shell:

`sudo sh -c "sudo sed 's/bar/baz/' <foo >foo2"`