# I got permission denied when run command with chroot

Tags: linux, bash, sudo

```
sudo chroot /tmp/jail /bin/echo 'test' > /home/someone/.bash_history
```

error log:
    -bash: /home/someone/.bash_history: Permission denied

Answer (score 1):

Your not running the whole command with sudo. try

```
sudo sh -c "chroot /tmp/jail /bin/echo 'test' > /home/someone/.bash_history"
```

The part after the redirect isnt running as root

For more examples

[How do I use sudo to redirect output to a location I don't have permission to write to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82256/how-do-i-use-sudo-to-redirect-output-to-a-location-i-dont-have-permission-to-wr)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the swift help! I think this need sudo sh which I don't have.

Comment: BTW, if I got sh sudo rights, then I think I can do everything with the root shell.

Comment: Yes sudo sh gives you a shell and -c runs it. Alternativly you can pipe it to sudo tee ?

Comment: But I don't have sudo tee enabled as well. :(