# How can I edit the proc/pid/oom_adj for a process on linux

Tags: linux, process, linux-kernel, out-of-memory

I have a situation where our server is killing a process that I don’t want to be killed.
My understanding is that this is happening because the kernel overcommits memory and is then forced to kill processes when it actually runs out of memory.
My understanding is that I can influence the kernel’s decision about which process to kill in this situation by adjusting the following value:

/proc/[pid]/oom_adj

This article explains all of this:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-dev/oom-killer-1911807.html

However, I get a Permission denied error when I try this as the ubuntu user:

**echo -15 > /proc/5641/oom_adj** 
-bash: /proc/5641/oom_adj: Permission denied

**sudo echo -15 > /proc/5641/oom_adj** 
gives the same error
My understanding is that this is because the shell is not executing the “>” command as root.

However, the work-arounds to this that I am familiar with are giving “No such file or directory” error.

**sudo bash -c ‘echo -15 > /proc/5641/oom_adj’**
-bash: /proc/5641/oom_adj’: No such file or directory

**sudo -s ‘echo -15 > /proc/5641/oom_adj’**
-bash: /proc/5641/oom_adj’: No such file or directory

What am I doing incorrect?

Comment: For anyone reading this the value should be between -16 to +15 (-17 to disable OOM) (this is for people coming from OOMScoreAdjust from systemd configuration.  The value range there is -1000 +1000).

Comment: Or use oom_score_adj which also have range from -1000 to +1000.

Answer (score 3):

you are running `echo` as `root` but actually is your shell trying to write in proc, look here for more explanation:
[How do I use sudo to redirect output to a location I don't have permission to write to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82256/how-do-i-use-sudo-to-redirect-output-to-a-location-i-dont-have-permission-to-wr)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
sudo bash -c "echo '-15' | tee /proc/5641/oom_adj"
```

It will ensure that the file is written as root because `bash` is running `tee` as root.