# apt-get proxy: Permission denied

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, proxy, xfce

I am trying to make a bash script that will set up a proxy on my computer running ubuntu studio. This [1] tells me that I should set up the proxies for apt-get and Update Manager by creating a file 95proxies in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/.

the problem is when I run this code.

```
sudo echo "Acquire::http::proxy "http://myproxy.server.com:8080/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://myproxy.server.com:8080/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://myproxy.server.com:8080/";
" > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/95proxies
```

I get:

```
bash: /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/95proxies: Permission denied
```

I was able to create the file with touch by

```
sudo touch /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/95proxies
```

but when I go to put data in the file I still get the error message above.

[1]
https://askubuntu.com/questions/150210/how-do-i-set-systemwide-proxy-servers-in-xubuntu-lubuntu-or-ubuntu-studio

Answer (score 3):

This is essentially the same problem as described in "[How do I use sudo to redirect output to a location I don't have permission to write to?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/82256/1157054)". That is, even though you're running `echo` with `sudo`, it's not `echo` that's writing to the file, it's your shell, and your shell doesn't have permission to write to that file.

One possible solution would be to use `sudo` with a program such as `tee` that actually does write to the file itself rather than relying on the shell:

```
echo "Acquire::http::proxy \"http://myproxy.server.com:8080/\";" | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/95proxies > /dev/null
```

For more possible solutions to this problem, see [How do I use sudo to redirect output to a location I don't have permission to write to?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/82256/1157054)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below command,

```
sudo sh -c '(echo "Acquire::http::proxy \"http://myproxy.server.com:8080/\";"; echo "Acquire::ftp::proxy \"ftp://myproxy.server.com:8080/\";"; echo "Acquire::https::proxy \"https://myproxy.server.com:8080/\";") > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/95proxies'
```

Because of the directory `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d` owned by root, you have to run the `echo` command in a separate subshell.

To add multiple lines to a  file through `echo` command, the syntax would be

```
(echo first line; echo second line) >> output file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo printf 'Acquire::http::proxy "http://myproxy.server.com:8080/;\nAcquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://myproxy.server.com:8080/;\nAcquire::https::proxy "https://myproxy.server.com:8080/;\n"' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/95proxies
```

To print new line character (\n) in a file you must use printf not echo.

In your case bash will use each line of the command as a new command (because of `;`, so `> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/95proxies` will be executed as a command without sudo.