# echo $HTTP as plain text

Tags: linux, bash, debian

I am trying to create a bash file which will modify some files but I have a problem with one command.
When I use `sudo echo "$HTTP["url"]" >> file.conf` I get error permission denied.
What I actually want is the file to have `$HTTP["url"]` inside, the $HTTP is not a variable in bash its just text.

Comment: To make it plain text use `'$HTTP["url"]'`, but I don't know what causes permission denied.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use sudo to redirect output to a location I don't have permission to write to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82256/how-do-i-use-sudo-to-redirect-output-to-a-location-i-dont-have-permission-to-wr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put it inside of single quotes, it should work

```
echo '$HTTP["url"]'
```