# sudo in bash, permission denied

Tags: linux, bash, sudo

I want to block usb mass storage in some of the systems in the LAN. I have written a bash script which will modify the file. I am running the script as default admin in ubuntu. But the script is not able to modify the file. I am getting the following error
"**bash: /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf: Permission denied**"

Below is my bash script

```
#/bin/bash
password='mypassword'                  #admin password of remote system
val='blacklist usb-storage'            #text which i want to add in the file
for sysName in $(cat systemDetails)    #systemDetails is file which stores
do
ssh $sysName 'echo '$password' | sudo -S echo '$val ' >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf'
echo
done
#script ends
```

NOTE: I have configured my system such that no ssh password is required.

Any pointers in this regard will be really helpful.

Comment: check: ls -la  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf.
see what are the permissions.

Comment: It looks like you have a problem with quoting. And why are you using sudo like that when you could have run it directly under root account?

Comment: The redirection in your command as it is written is processed by the shell that invokes sudo, you need to write/redirect to be initiated by the process started by sudo (the elevated process).

Comment: to use root account i have to pair my ssh-key of root with all the systems which i want to configure

Comment: @griffonvulture: the result is
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1627 Apr 27 11:00 /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
ssh $sysName "echo $password | sudo -S sh -c 'echo $val >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf'"
```

Comment: While this code may solve the problem, a few words of explanation would help all of the readers to gain more insight into the solution.

Comment: The accepted answer in this post explains a lot: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82256/how-do-i-use-sudo-to-redirect-output-to-a-location-i-dont-have-permission-to-wr