# Change host file with script on Mac

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, sudo, hosts

I'm trying to append a line to the hosts file on a mac.
The command I'm using is:

```
sudo echo "192.168.99.100 test" >> /private/etc/hosts
```

This method does work on windows & linux but on Mac I do not have the permissions to run this even when running it in `sudo` mode.

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix this?

StefanJanssen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use sudo to redirect output to a location I don't have permission to write to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82256/how-do-i-use-sudo-to-redirect-output-to-a-location-i-dont-have-permission-to-wr)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `echo '192.168.99.100 test' | sudo tee -a /private/etc/hosts`.

`>>` is syntax of the shell itself, which is running as your user.  `sudo echo "192.168.99.100 test" >> /private/etc/hosts` runs `echo "192.168.99.100 test"` as root and the `>>` "pipe to file" is run as your user.

`tee` is an ordinary command you can run as root with `sudo` which outputs to both stdout and a file, so `echo 'line' | sudo tee -a file` will do what you want.  `tee -a` will append to the file instead of overwriting it.

Comment: @trojanfoe What looks like rubbish?

Comment: @trojanfoe It's not, the redirection is run in the current shell which does not have sudo priveleges.

Comment: `sudo` is just an ordinary command which takes in input via command line arguments.  `>>` is interpreted by the shell instead of being added as an argument to the command.  That's why `echo 'hello' >> file` doesn't display `hello >> file` and instead writes `hello` to the file `file`.