# Sed in place on privileged symlink

Tags: bash, sed

Once upon a time I used `sed` and `tee` combined to alter a privileged file in place. Because the shell itself doesn't have root privileges I had to get creative to write command output into files:

```
sed -r 'script' "/etc/hosts" | sudo tee "/etc/hosts" 1>/dev/null
```

At the time, this worked wonderfully. It was only after I started using my hosts file for ad blocking that I realised the pipe is limited to a buffer, after which tee will gladly overwrite the file and the rest of the file will disappear.

I also considered a much simpler version:

```
sed -r 'script' "/etc/hosts" > "/etc/hosts.tmp" && sudo mv "/etc/hosts.tmp" "/etc/hosts"
```

Unfortunately, this too won't work, since the file in question is a symlink. A `mv` would overwrite the symlink, as opposed to the file underneath.

My current solution is this:

```
sed -r 'script' "/etc/hosts" | sudo tee "/etc/hosts.tmp" 1>/dev/null &&
    sudo cat "/etc/hosts.tmp" | sudo tee "/etc/hosts" 1>/dev/null &&
    sudo rm "/etc/hosts.tmp"
```

Ew! How verbose!

Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: Useless use of `cat`: use `sudo tee /etc/hosts < /etc/hosts.tmp`.

Comment: Useless spam of useless saying. That wouldn't work because there's no guarantee `/etc/hosts.tmp` created through `sudo tee` is readable by the shell

Comment: You're creating the file; there's no need to use `sudo` to create the file (nor is there any need to create the temporary file in `/etc` in the first place).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using GNU sed, you could use its `-i` in-place edition flag, so that the results of its execution is directly saved to the file it process. Then you just have to `sudo` the `sed` command and you should be fine.

Additionnaly to write the file rather than the link, use sed's `--follow-symlinks` flag.

In other cases, check [this answer to a similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/82278/1678362).

Comment: Yes but then I'll still need cleanup won't I? (And if sed kicks the bucket I'll have half a file) **Edit** Never mind, apparently the leftover files are only if you provide a suffix to `-i`. Though I wonder how it can tell the difference between a suffix and another flag...

Comment: Actually I'm going to have to uncheck this answer - turns out `sed -i` has the same problem as `mv` - it's turning my symlink into a file! (I'll try readlink and realpath and when I find a combo that works I'll tick you and post in the question)

Comment: @JV let me check if I can find something

Comment: @JV see my edited answer, there's a `--follow-symlinks` flag that will solve your problem