# Creating pub key from private key using ssh

Tags: ssh, command, ssh-keys, ssh-keygen

I have executed below command for creating public key from private key, it shows me an error and asking for passphrase.

```
~# ssh-keygen -y -f key.pem > mykey.pub

@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0644 for 'key.pem' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
bad permissions: ignore key: key.pem
Enter passphrase:
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0644 for 'key.pem' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
bad permissions: ignore key: key.pem
load failed
```

Thanks(in advance)

Answer (score 0):

ssh checks if your private key file could be read by other users. Since it is the case, it refuses to go further.

just `chmod 600 key.pem` and run the tool again (read-write rights only for current user)

Comment: i gave a  permission as 600 and run again .It shows like this still  sudo ssh-keygen -y -f jj.pem > mykey.pub
-bash: mykey.pub: Permission denied.Eventhough iam running as sudo user

Comment: As you see the problem is related to `mykey.pub` now! delete the old `mykey.pub` file and retry. Or you are running this from a read-only device like a CD-ROM.

Comment: No, it's not read-only device problem and deleting the file won't help either. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82256/how-do-i-use-sudo-to-redirect-output-to-a-location-i-dont-have-permission-to-wr

Comment: then check umask. Can you create a file like this: `echo hello > mykey.pub` ?

Answer (score 0):

Quick bash-only hack:

```
ssh-keygen -y -f <(cat key.pem) > mykey.pub
```

The process substition empolyed here should create a named pipe that has limited permissions.