# How to use output redirection with sudo?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sudo, file-access

I wish to write text from stdin to a file that is owned by root.

I'm doing this programmatically across an SSH connection - essentially from a script - so using a text editor is out of the question. There is no terminal. The process is entirely automated.

Given that [a] root elevation can be obtained via `sudo`, and [b] files can be written to using `cat` with redirection, I assumed the following would work:

```
ssh user@host sudo cat >the-file
```

Unfortunately, the redirection is applied to `sudo`, not to `cat`. How can I apply redirection to `cat` in this example?

Comment: In fact, you could use a text editor even across a SSH connection, editors like vim or nano should work fine. Try to explain better your case with SSH connection. You already logged when you try to redirect?

Comment: Your sudo command does not appear to be correct. It should be `sudo -u user -h host cat > the-file`. That works on my system. "I'm doing this across an SSH connection, so using a text editor is out of the question". That conclusion is not as self evident as you make it. Editors such as `vim`, `nano` and even `emacs -nw` work just fine in a terminal.

Comment: @John1024 yes, I could use tee, but I'd rather fix the redirect problem directly.

Comment: @paulequilibrio I'm calling the command programmatically. I can issue commands, but I don't have a terminal.

Comment: @kaylum That'd be great if `-h` was a standard parameter to `sudo` across all platforms. On a Mac, for example, there is no such option. You were right that my command was wrong: I've edited the question to fix it.

Comment: @John1024 It means your `tee` solution doesn't use redirects. I want to get redirection working so I can use `cat`, or any other program in the future that requires redirection. Please see my amended commandline.

Comment: @SodAlmighty Might be a good idea to tag or mention your system then. Macs don't run Linux (which this question is tagged with).

Comment: @John1024 Nope, that doesn't work. `ssh user@host sudo bash -c 'ls >/test'` results in "bash: /test.: Permission denied". And of course, if `ls` redirection fails, obviously `cat` redirection will fail also.

Comment: @kaylum The server is running Linux, and my question concerned the arguments to `ssh`, and subsequently to `sudo` *on the target system*. My question didn't ask for `ssh` to be omitted entirely and `sudo` to be used directly; therefore my client system is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @SodAlmighty I see that you have now completely changed the question.

Comment: No, I've clarified it, by moving a paragraph up, and correcting my commandline. I *did* say I was using SSH. Are you *trying* to be argumentative? Sure, I made a mistake in my quoted commandline, but aside from that I have not "changed my question".

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/82256/5201578

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The normal pattern to do this is:

```
ssh user@host 'cat | sudo tee the-file'
```

`tee` redirects output to a file and can be run with `sudo`.

If you want to mimic `>>` where the file is appended-to, use `sudo tee -a`.

You'll also need to be sure to quote your command as above, so that the pipe isn't interpreted by the local shell.

**Edit**

The `tee` command [is part of POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tee.html), so you can rely on it existing.

To redirect Standard Error as well:

```
ssh user@host 'some_command 2>&1 | sudo tee output-file'
```

Comment: So redirection *cannot* be used in a `sudo` command? For example, if `tee` (and I suppose `dd`) didn't exist on the system, I'd be boned? Or if I wanted to redirect stderr as well, I'd be boned then also?

Comment: See my edit :) Yeah, I mean, you could probably use `ssh <host> 'sudo sh -c "cat >the-file"'`, but you'll quickly get into "two many levels of quoting" problems and I'm unsure if redirection will work properly through `sh -c` over ssh :)

Comment: You can use redirection with any command you like, but the redirection takes place before the command runs. (In fact, your question is wrong; the redirection applies to the entire `ssh` command line, not to `sudo`.)  You could so something like `sudo sh -c 'cat >output-file'` to get privileged redirection, but `sudo tee` is much simpler.  With `sudo`, you should always strive to restrict the privileged operation to the simplest possible command.

Comment: `tee` obviously also prints to standard output; you can use `tee file >/dev/null` to avoid having the results display on the console.