# Apply sudo on whole command line (stdout redirection)

Tags: shell, zsh, sudo

I'm trying the following :

```
sudo iptables-save > /etc/iptables/Firewall.rules
```

but I get `permission denied: Firewall.rules` even if `ls -l` tells me that root has writing permission for this file :

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  362 Aug  3 14:26 Firewall.rules
```

Is it normal?

When I run `su` and then directly try this redirection as superuser (without `sudo`), I have no problem.

Even if I'm not sure, my guess is that `sudo` only applies on the `iptables-save` command and not on the `>` redirection (`sudo(iptables-save) > file` instead of `sudo(iptables-save > file)` if I had to express the priorities with parenthesis and pseudo code).

If I'm right about this, how could I apply `sudo` to my whole command line?

If I'm wrong, what did I miss?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82256/how-do-i-use-sudo-to-redirect-output-to-a-location-i-dont-have-permission. Hopefully this will help.

Comment: It does, my bad I didn't find this result. I'll mark my post as duplicate.
Thank you for your help!