# Using the right quotes for exported variables inside a sudo shell envsubst command

Tags: bash

I have this bash code that replace some variables in a template text file and write the result somewhere. This works :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
PROJECTFOLDER=$1
USER=$2

export PROJECTFOLDER USER
CONFIGVARS='$PROJECTFOLDER:$USER'

envsubst "$CONFIGVARS" < template.conf > /home/me/config.inc.php
```

and a template.conf like so :

```
<h1>${USER}</h1>
<h2>${PROJECTFOLDER}</h2>
```

When called with :

```
./script foo bar
```

This gives :

```
<h1>foo</h1>
<h2>bar</h2>
```

But if I want to save the output to a folder with sudo or root it does not work, [as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82256/how-do-i-use-sudo-to-redirect-output-to-a-location-i-dont-have-permission-to-wr).

What I should do is running the command in a sudo shell (I don't want to use the tee or dd method to keep it simple).

```
sudo sh -c 'envsubst "$CONFIGVARS" < template.conf > /etc/config.inc.php'
```

But whatever combination of quotes ands brackets I try, it gives either

```
<h1>${USER}</h1>
<h2>${PROJECTFOLDER}</h2>
```

or nothing :

```
<h1></h1>
<h2></h2>
```

**Solution**
Thanks to l0b0 :

```
envsubst "$CONFIGVARS" < template.conf | sudo tee /etc/config.inc.php
```

Comment: Variables aren't exported to `sudo`.

Comment: try adding '\' before the $ as in: `envsubst "\$CONFIGVARS"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you'll want to do is pipe the command to `sudo tee /home/me/config.inc.php`.