# Modify /etc/hosts file using a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos6, sshpass

I do not have passwordless ssh enabled between my two servers a and b. So I am using sshpass to connect to the server b from a.

I have a requirement to add host entries in the /etc/hosts of server b from a. But the user that i am logging into server b is non-root user but has sudo privileges to edit files owned by root.

How do i add host entries to /etc/hosts of server b from server a through a shell script while using sshpass.

Here is the script that was tried:

```
#!/bin/bash

export SSHPASS="password"
SSHUSER=ciuser
WPC_IP=10.8.150.28

sshpass -e ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' $SSHUSER@$WPC_IP "echo test >> /etc/hosts"
```

Output:

```
bash test.sh
Warning: Permanently added '10.8.150.28' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
bash: /etc/hosts: Permission denied
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the command you tried and how it failed?

Comment: @thatotherguy: updated the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`sudo` [doesn't work with redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82256/how-do-i-use-sudo-to-redirect-output-to-a-location-i-dont-have-permission-to-wr) directly, so you can use `sudo tee -a` to append to a file:

```
echo '1.2.3.4 test' | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts
```

In your command, this would be:

```
sshpass -e ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' "$SSHUSER@$WPC_IP" "echo test | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts"
```

Note that this requires passwordless sudo access without a tty, which is not necessarily the same as your sudo privileges.