# bash shell script: writing to file does not work

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I am super new to shell scripting and I am trying to write the contents of my string variable to file. When I echo the variable before using it to write into the file, it works well. But when the script is completed, there is no update to the file.

My code is:

```
    echo $str
    touch $HOME/Documents/config.txt
    sudo chmod u+w $HOME/Documents/config.txt
    echo "$str" >> sudo $HOME/Documents/config.txt
    sudo cp sudo $HOME/Documents/config.txt $HOME/.ssh/
    echo $str
    echo "configuration file updated!"
```

I have tried giving it write permission, different ways of writing to the file. Also earlier I thought, .ssh folder is the source of my problem so as you can see, I am first trying to write the file somewhere else and then trying to move it to the .ssh folder. But wherever I try to rite it, file is still empty at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you `touch`-ed the document, it belongs to you. That means you don't have to use `sudo` at all. You have to remove all traces of `sudo` from your script.

```
echo $str
touch $HOME/Documents/config.txt
chmod u+w $HOME/Documents/config.txt
echo "$str" >> $HOME/Documents/config.txt
cp $HOME/Documents/config.txt $HOME/.ssh/
echo $str
echo "configuration file updated!"
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `sudo` from here:

```
echo "$str" >> sudo $HOME/Documents/config.txt
```

You're piping the output of echo into the file. `sudo` is used to run a command with root privileges.

If you don't have write permissions to the file: [How do I use sudo to redirect output to a location I don't have permission to write to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82256/how-do-i-use-sudo-to-redirect-output-to-a-location-i-dont-have-permission-to-wr)