# Permission error while trying to add a content to a remote host's file

Tags: bash, icinga2

I have a script that should create a file and add content to a file on the hosts listed in a file:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read f; do

   sshpass -p "mypassword" ssh-copy-id myusername@"$f"
   ssh -ntt myusername@"$f" '
        echo mypassword | sudo -S touch  /etc/sudoers.d/10_icinga_check_postfix_queue || true
        echo mypassword | sudo -S echo "icinga ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_postfix_queue" > /etc/sudoers.d/10_icinga_check_postfix_queue || true' </dev/null

done < linux-list.txt
```

But I get an error and not sure why. can you please help?

```
bash: line 1: /etc/sudoers.d/10_icinga_check_postfix_queue: Permission denied
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use sudo to redirect output to a location I don't have permission to write to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82256/how-do-i-use-sudo-to-redirect-output-to-a-location-i-dont-have-permission-to-wr)

Comment: I tried that solution but no luck - echo my password | sudo -S chmod u+w /etc/sudoers.d/10_icinga_check_postfix_queue

Comment: @IrinaI Not that one; the `sudo bash -c ...` solution should work in your case. Note that it's inside a single-quoted string, so you can't use single-quotes (without complications). Also, make sure the file doesn't end up with insecure permissions, or `sudo` will reject it.

Comment: @GordonDavisson thank you but it still doesn't work, maybe I am doing it wrong: sudo bash -c "{ echo 'icinga ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_postfix_queue, /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/contrib/restart_service.sh' > /etc/sudoers.d/10_icinga_check_postfix_queue }"

Comment: You're probably running into trouble because of the single-quotes in that. Try replacing them with escaped double-quotes (`\"`).

Comment: @GordonDavisson
Still fails... Can you please type the command  you  have in mind? I tried every combination I  knew of ... sudo bash -c "{ echo 'icinga ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_postfix_queue, /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/contrib/restart_service.sh' > /etc/sudoers.d/10_icinga_check_postfix_queue }"

Answer (score 1):

How about this refactoring of Gordon's answer?  There's no need to separately `touch` the file you are about to overwrite anyway.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r f; do
   sshpass -p "mypassword" ssh-copy-id myusername@"$f"
   ssh -ntt myusername@"$f" '
        echo mypassword | sudo -S bash -c "echo \"icinga ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_postfix_queue, /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/contrib/restart_service.sh\" > /etc/sudoers.d/10_icinga_check_postfix_queue" || true' </dev/null    
done < linux-list.txt
```

Notice also the (re-) introduction of the `-r` option to `read`. It's probably not crucial here, but getting used to it can help avoid unpleasant surprises where it does make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read f; do

   sshpass -p "mypassword" ssh-copy-id myusername@"$f"
   ssh -ntt myusername@"$f" '
        echo mypassword | sudo -S touch  /etc/sudoers.d/10_icinga_check_postfix_queue || true
        echo mypassword | sudo -S bash -c "echo \"icinga ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_postfix_queue, /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/contrib/restart_service.sh\" > /etc/sudoers.d/10_icinga_check_postfix_queue" || true' </dev/null

done < linux-list.txt
```

This will run the entire `echo ... >file` command in a sudo shell (rather than just running `echo` with sudo, and the `>file` part unprivileged). The tricky thing here is the quoting: there's a single-quoted string that's being passed to `ssh` as an argument (the commands to run on the remote computer); inside that, there's a double-quoted string being passed to `bash -c` as the command run (as root), and inside that, there's *another* quoted string. Since quotes don't nest, the innermost quoted string uses escaped double-quotes (`\"`), which get passed unchanged when the single-quoted string is parsed on the local computer, then when the outer double-quoted string gets parsed by the remote shell the escapes get removed, so by the time the remote root shell sees it, it's a normal double-quoted string. Yes, this is a mess, but it should work (though I haven't tested it).

Comment: The second `sudo` should not need a password if the `sudo` credential caching is set up properly. I don't think I've seen a site paranoid enough to disable it altogether.

Comment: @tripleee Good point; also, as you pointed out in your answer, the `touch` is redundant anyway.