# Shared Named Pipes Between Docker Container And Host - Cross Platform

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I have a named pipe that's been created in a Ubuntu Docker container ([ubuntu-python](https://github.com/rcarmo/ubuntu-python)). I'd like to send data into this pipe from the host operating system and read data from the pipe from the container.

**Within Container:**

I created the pipe within the container using

`mkfifo stream`

I then read from the stream using

`cat stream`

As expected, the command appears to hang because it's waiting for some input

**Docker file**

I then shared the named pipe to the host operating system using a volume

```
    volumes:
      - ./audio:/app/audio # stream is inside /app/audio
```

**Host OS:**

I ran

`sudo bash -c "echo test > stream"`

I expect this to write to the stream, this should cause the original `cat stream` command to unhang and print `test`, but both the input and the output commands continue to hang, showing that the data isn't actually being moved into the container. The reason I use `bash -c` is because I need the [redirection to run as root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82256/how-do-i-use-sudo-to-redirect-output-to-a-location-i-dont-have-permission-to-wr).

This series of commands running on the host OS works perfectly, but once I introduce the volume and the movement of data between the host and the container, it no longer works. How can I write data to a named pipe from the host OS and have it show up in the container?

For reference, the host is WSL running Ubuntu 20.04, but I plan to deploy this on a Raspberry Pi 3B+ running Raspbian Lite. I also want to distribute this to other users of an open source project, so the solution should be host agnostic (atleast for hosts that can actually run a Ubuntu container).

Comment: Can you provide the exact commands you ran, and the exact order you ran them in?  "I ran `mkfifo` in a container" with the Compose bind mount fragment after that are throwing me off a little.

Comment: These are the commands I ran in the order I ran them. I left out semantic commands like `docker-compose up` and removed the full file locations, but that's it. When I say I ran `mkfifo` in a container, I used `docker exec -it <container name> /bin/bash` to access the shell and ran that command in the `/app/audio` folder which is mounted using a volume to the host OS. Hope that clears it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `mkfifo -m a+rw stream` will allow any user to write to the stream instead of just root users. This is because the `-m` allows you to specify permissions on the pipe similar to `chmod`. As a result, the redirection no longer needs to run as root.

Now we can simply use `echo test > stream` from the host OS, and the output will appear properly in the container.

I'm not sure why writing to the pipe using `bash -c` didn't actually move the data into the container, but the `-m` flag for `mkfifo` means we don't need to use it.