# Writing the current proces pid to cgroups.procs fails with permission denied error

Tags: linux, go, cgroups

I am trying to write a pid to a manually created cgroup but I am unable to do so.

While writing, I am getting the following error:

```
open /sys/fs/cgroup/pids/scratch-container-cgroup0049cba7-8f9e-42ec-9646-9b1babbfebc3/cgroups.procs: permission denied
```

The file has the following permissions:

```
[~~]$ ls -l cgroup.procs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Feb 14 23:27 cgroup.procs
[~~]$
```

The code that I am using to write it as follows in Go

```
    procs := filepath.Join(containerCgroupPath, "cgroups.procs")
    currentPid := strconv.Itoa(os.Getpid())
    log.Printf("current pid is %s", currentPid)
    if err := ioutil.WriteFile(procs, []byte(currentPid), 0777); err != nil {
        return err
    }
```

However, using bash also gives out the same error.

```
sudo echo "100" > cgroup.procs 
bash: cgroup.procs: Permission denied
```

I am not sure what I am missing about cgroups here that could be used to write. I am on Centos that is running systemd.

I am able to write to `pids.max` and `notify_on_release`

I will really appreciate insights here.

Comment: Have you go selinux running?

Comment: Hi Raman, apologies for getting back late. I checked if selinux is enabled using the following command

```
$ getenforce
Disabled
```

and I see that it is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Can't speak about the go code, but the problem in bash is most likely down to this:

[How do I use sudo to redirect output to a location I don't have permission to write to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82256/how-do-i-use-sudo-to-redirect-output-to-a-location-i-dont-have-permission-to-wr)

If that doesn't help you, please also check that you have permissions to write to the `cgroup.procs` file in the common parent of process `100` (`echo /proc/100/cgroup`) and the cgroup where you're moving it to (`/sys/fs/cgroup/pids/scratch-container-cgroup0049cba7-8f9e-42ec-9646-9b1babbfebc3/`).

Answer (score 0):

The correct file name in your code should be "cgroup.procs" instead of "cgroups.procs"

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue. I tried the following and it works

```
echo "100" | sudo tee cgroup.procs
```

But I could not explain why.

Comment: In `sudo echo "100" > cgroup.procs` the `sudo` applies to the `echo` not the bash redirection which actually accesses the file. In `echo "100" | sudo tee cgroup.procs` the `sudo` applies to the `tee` which is the process that actually accesses the file.